# purpose of with() in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I seeing a java script function on web page which used with() at the top of function and rest of function implementation doing within with() statement. I put the function code below for reference.

```
function calculate()
{
     with (document.loan)
    {
      var loan = parseFloat(loan_amount.value);
      //function implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Form is define like this in page with name of loan.

```
<form name="loan" id="loan-form">
   <input type="text" id="loan_amount"/>
  // remaining form elements here
</form>
```

What is doing this "with" statement and what's it scope ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's "with" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)

Comment: Also useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/61552/1846192 and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/185283/1846192 will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript’s `with` statement was intended to provide a shorthand for writing recurring accesses to objects.

So instead of writing

```
myObj.obj2.obj3.bing = true;
myObj.obj2.obj3.bang = true;
```

You can write

```
with (myObj.obj2.obj3) {
    bing = true;
    bang = true;
}
```

Comment: But you probably shouldn't per http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/