# multiple setTimeout calls within a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm trying to code the game Simon in HTML/JS and it's all working, except for the part where the game flashes the sequence so you know what the new sequence is. Essentially what I have is:

```
for(var i in thePattern){
    var obj = document.getElementById(thePattern[i]);
    window.setTimeout(colorON(obj),500);
    window.setTimeout(colorOFF(obj),1000);
}
```

where colorON and colorOFF are:

```
function colorON(obj){
    if(obj.id == "red"){
        obj.style.backgroundColor="#ff5555";
    }else if(obj.id == "blue"){
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#5555ff";
    }else if(obj.id == "green"){
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#88ff88";
    }else{
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#ffffaa";
    }
}
function colorOFF(obj){
    if(obj.id == "red"){
        obj.style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";
    }else if(obj.id == "blue"){
        obj.style.backgroundColor="#0000ff";
    }else if(obj.id == "green"){
        obj.style.backgroundColor="#22ff22";
    }else{
        obj.style.backgroundColor="#ffff00";
    }
}
```

What it seems to be doing is going through the entire for loop and starting all the timers and then then all the timers go off so quickly that the colors don't even seem to flash.

Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated.

---

Now it is flashing correctly and the closure is working correctly, but it is flashing all the colors at the same time. I've tried putting the closure within another `setTimeout`, however, that just creates other problems.

---

**SOLVED** thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You really need to learn about switch statements.

Comment: First fix the problems pointed out in the answers here.  Then when you find the next issue that fixing this will expose, have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    colorON(obj);
},500);
```

Right now, you're calling `colorON(obj)` immediately and passing its output to `setTimeout`, which makes it appear like `setTimeout` is firing immediately.

`obj` is also passed by reference, so by the time all of your functions will run, `obj` will refer to the *last* element in your loop. To get around that, you have to pass `obj` by value by shadowing it:

```
(function(obj) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        colorON(obj);
    }, 500);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        colorOFF(obj);
    }, 1000);
})(obj);
```

Comment: You'll hit the *"creating a function in a loop"* problem. OP should keep the same code, and have the functions return a function.

Comment: This is true, but fixing it will cause another issue.  Calling `setTimeout` in a loop, the `obj` value will always be the final value of the last iteration.

Comment: @squint: I'd rather just shadow `obj`. Having `colorON` return a function is counter-intuitive.

Comment: There's nothing intuitive about IIFE's... evidenced by all the people that ask about them... but ultimately the only "intuintive" solution is for JS to have block scope... again, evidenced by the fact that so many people expect it.

Comment: @squint: That's what the `let` keyword is for. Sadly, nobody supports it.

Comment: Well... almost nobody, but certainly not enough to be able to use it. :(

Comment: @Blender regarding let keyword: It's true its support isn't widespread yet, but you can use the with keyword to similar effect. 

EDIT: Googled and found this from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/185283/681290

Comment: Could anybody explain little bit more this application of variable shadowing please? Everywhere it's explained on basic concept of local vs. global variable. But the code above is quite difficult to understand for me. Especially the purpose of `(obj)` at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it! So the code runs right away and sets the setTimeout with whatever the function returns.

change

```
window.setTimeout(colorON(obj),500);
window.setTimeout(colorOFF(obj),1000);
```

to

```
for(var i in thePattern){
    var obj = document.getElementById(thePattern[i]);
    (function(obj) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){colorON(obj);},500);
        window.setTimeout(function(){colorOFF(obj);},1000);
    })(obj);
}
```

and code showing you how to do with with a switch or an object to get rid of the if/else logic

```
function colorON(obj) {
    var color = "";
    switch (obj.id) {
        case "red":
            color = "#ff5555"
            break;
        case "blue":
            color = "#5555ff"
            break;
        case "green":
            color = "#88ff88"
            break;
        default:
            color = "#ffffaa"
    }
    obj.style.background = color;
}

var colorsOff = {
    "red": "#ff0000",
        "blue": "#0000ff",
        "green": "#22ff22",
        "default": "#ffff00"
}



    function colorOFF(obj) {
        var color = colorsOff[obj.id] || colors["default"];
        obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }


var thePattern = {
    "one": "red",
        "two": "blue",
        "three": "green"
}


for (var i in thePattern) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(thePattern[i]);
    (function (obj) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            colorON(obj);
        }, 500);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            colorOFF(obj);
        }, 1000);
    })(obj);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/brjgc/

Comment: You'll hit the *"creating a function in a loop"* problem. OP should keep the same code, and have the functions return a function.