# What is wrong with my javascript scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

The following alerts `2` every time.

```
function timer() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        var j = i;
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(j);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

timer();
```

Shouldn't `var j = i;` set the `j` into the individual scope of the setTimeout?

Whereas if I do this:

```
function timer() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        (function (j) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert(j);
            }, 1000);
        })(i);
    }
}

timer();
```

It alerts `0`, `1`, `2` like it should.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "like it should" - did you mean "like I want it to"? :)

Comment: You are only missing, that Javascript is broken as hell, I had the exact same WTF moment about a week ago … :(

Comment: @VisioN Not really. I know how they work. I am wondering why they do not work like they should in this case.

Comment: @Neal Well, I personally see that `j` is not initialized in the scope of `setTimeout` but in the scope of `timer` function, whereas in the second example you create an anonymous function, where you pass `i`, implicitly initialising `j` in the scope of closure. This creates and executes 3 functional blocks, setting 3 timeouts at once.

Comment: @VisioN for loops don't have their own scopes?

Comment: @Neal No, for loops don't have their own scope. In the next version of javascript there will be a `let` instead of `var` that will fix this.

Comment: @Neal No, variables defined in `for` loops are in the same scope the `for` loop is in. **REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Parameters.

Comment: It surprises me that someone who has answered over 1000 JavaScript/jQuery questions doesn't know how variable scope works in the language.

Comment: @BlueSkies It did to me too. Hence I asked the question. [I learn new things every day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914077/what-is-wrong-with-my-javascript-scope#comment29631015_19914115)

Comment: @filmor—and you are missing that closures are a very powerful feature of the language. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Javascript is an curly-bracket language, all other curly-bracket languages I know of use block scope, so this was completely unexpected to me. This has nothing to do with closures, which are IMHO abused to regain block-scope in this case.

Comment: @filmor—it seemed more like a closure issue than not understanding variable scope. I don't see lack of block scope as an issue, if someone understands closures they should know how to fix that. Anyway, it seems *let* in [*ED 6*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) will deliver function and block scope without disrupting current use of closures. It will be quite a while before it can be used on the general web though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Javascript has function scope. This means that

```
for(...) {
    var j = i;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
var j;
for(...) {
    j = i;
}
```

In fact, this is how Javascript compilers will actually treat this code. And, of course, this causes your little "trick" to fail, because `j` will be incremented before the function in `setTimeout` gets called, i.e. `j` now doesn't really do anything different than `i`, it's just an alias with the same scope.

If Javascript were to have block scope, your trick would work, because `j` would be a new variable within every iteration.

What you need to do is create a new scope:

```
for(var i = ...) {
    (function (j) {
        // you can safely use j here now
        setTimeout(...);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the code from defining it like this?

Comment: Just edited a pseudo-code solution in.

Comment: Haha that is basically what I do in the end of my OP.... silly hacks.

Comment: @Neal You edited that last part into your question, didn't you? Because if not, I must be really blind to not have seen it when writing my answer.

Comment: @IngoBürk Nope. That was there the whole time. That was the whole point of my question... If that was the **only** way to do it.

Comment: Oh… then. It's about time I go to sleep. Well at least you (hopefully?) have an explanation on why the other way doesn't work.

Comment: Yea... I did not realize that javascript did not have block scope. Weird. Learn new things every day.

Answer (score 6):

The alternative the the IIFE is a function factory:

```
function timer() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        setTimeout(createTimerCallback(i), 1000);
    }
}

function createTimerCallback(i) {
    return function() {
       alert(i);
    };
}

timer();
```

---

This being said, this is one of the most asked questions in the javascript tag. See:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: Sooo hacky!! Why does javascript make you do these things?

Comment: It's not hacky, it's just how scope works in this language.

Comment: There's nothing hacky about it: Function scope versus block scope is a simple language feature which comes with effects like this. It just feels hacky as a lot of other languages have block scope which would prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the (normally abused) keyword `with`:

```
function timer() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        with({j: i}) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert(j);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}

timer();
```

It creates a new scope like functions do, but without the awkward syntax.  I first saw it here:  [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's “with” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)

Comment: I like that you gave a `with` example, but it doesn't create a scope "like functions do". There are important differences, which led to its removal from "strict mode".

Comment: @BlueSkies Pseudo-scope, then.  For the most part with practical use, it acts like it does.