# Calling a function within a Nested Object

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

I have an object, nested within a parent object. The inner object has 2 functions and one needs to call the other. I assumed I could call `this.theFunction()`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
var views = {
  settings: {
    init: function() {
      this.doSomething(withThing);
    },

    doSomething: function(with) {
      // NEVER GETS CALLED
    }
  }
};
```

In this case, `this` seems to reference a `DOMWindow` rather than the `views.settings` object as I was expecting. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

The `views.settings.init()` function is called as a callback. An external process calls `template.init(view, views.settings.init);`. The latter argument is a callback. Within `template.init()`, the callback is simply called as `callback()`. For clarity (hopefully), here's a snippet of how we get to `views.settings.init`:

```
template.init(view, views.settings.init);
var template: {
  init: function() {
    callback();
  }
}
```

What would cause the context to get lost and what can I do to get it back so that `this` references the `views.settings` object?

Comment: Whatever's calling your "init" function is doing so in such a way as to lose the context (the `this` value).  The default value for `this` is the global context (unless you're in "strict" mode).

Comment: `views.settings.doSomething()`?

Comment: also `with` is a reserved keyword, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement

Comment: Question updated to try to offer some clarity. I wasn't actually using `with` as a variable. It was a poor choice in my example. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var views = {
   settings: {
    init: function() {
        var withThing = 'withThing';
        this.doSomething(withThing);
    },

    doSomething: function(withThing) {
      // NEVER GETS CALLED
        alert(withThing)
    }
  }
};

views.settings.init();
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2F29/3/)