# Why does Knockoutjs use "with" statement and "new Function" to implement its bindingProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, binding, vue.js

Why not a parser in angularjs or regular expression replacing in vue? Which one is better? Is it OK to use "with" statement?

**Konckoutjs**

```
function createBindingsStringEvaluator(bindingsString, options) {
    // Build the source for a function that evaluates "expression"
    // For each scope variable, add an extra level of "with" nesting
    // Example result: with(sc1) { with(sc0) { return (expression) } }
    var rewrittenBindings = ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings(bindingsString, options),
        functionBody = "with($context){with($data||{}){return{" + rewrittenBindings + "}}}";
    return new Function("$context", "$element", functionBody);
}
```

**Angularjs**

```
  var Parser = function(lexer, $filter, options) {
      this.lexer = lexer;
      this.$filter = $filter;
      this.options = options;
      this.ast = new AST(this.lexer);
      this.astCompiler = options.csp ? new ASTInterpreter(this.ast, $filter) :
      new ASTCompiler(this.ast, $filter);
  };
  ...
```

**vue**

```
  function compileExpFns (exp, needSet) {
      if (improperKeywordsRE.test(exp)) {
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && _.warn(
          'Avoid using reserved keywords in expression: ' + exp)
      }
      // reset state
      saved.length = 0
      // save strings and object literal keys
      var body = exp
          .replace(saveRE, save)
          .replace(wsRE, '')
      // rewrite all paths
      // pad 1 space here becaue the regex matches 1 extra char
      body = (' ' + body)
          .replace(pathReplaceRE, rewrite)
          .replace(restoreRE, restore)
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Your question is probably better directed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/knockoutjs

Answer (score 0):

According to [JavaScript’s with statement and why it’s deprecated](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html) there is no safety and performance issues for JR's [microtemplate](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) because all the attributes only for output.

FYI [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's “with” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement)