# Javascript "with" operator removal

Tags: javascript, with-statement

I recently ran into some issues with a plugin and outlined the issue in this post: [With operator & dashes in object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166423/with-operator-dashes-in-object-keys) and wanted to know if the modifications I've made below cover the scenarios that the `with` scope blocks would have covered.

I've modified some code to remove the `with` operator and I'm wondering if I've replicated everything properly in doing so.

Here is the original code:

```
var test = new Function('$f','$c','with($f){with($c){return{'+ declarations +'}}}'));
```

Where `$f` and `$c` are passed objects (From what I could tell, `$f` shouldn't ever have a property of `$c`). The `declarations` variable is a string that has a colon in it (EX: "value:color") and available within the scope.

Here is my modified code:

```
var test = function($f, $c, declarations) {
        var result = {};
        var value = "";
        var split = declarations.split(":");
        if (split.length < 2) {
          throw new Error("Declaration is in an invalid format");
        }
        if ($f[$c] !== undefined && $f[$c][split[1]]) {
          value = $f[$c][split[1]];
        }
        else if ($c[split[1]]) {
          value =  $c[split[1]];
        }
        else if ($f[split[1]]) {
          value =  $f[split[1]];
        }
        else {
          value =  "" + split[1];
        }
        var key = split[0];
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
};
```

Everything appears to work as it did previously, but this modification now handles the use case where the `declarations` variable could have a dash in it (EX: "value:background-color").  Additionally the `declarations` variable is passed into the function, to ensure it's defined.

Comment: This may be a question better suited for Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @m69 Wow, I hadn't realized that existed!  Thanks :)