# const doesn't work in Edge 15 developer tools

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

I am running Edge/15.15063. ['Can I Use' says const should work.](http://caniuse.com/#search=const)

Running:

```
const x = 'woo'
```

Then:

```
console.log(x)
```

Returns

```
'x' is undefined
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Why isn't const working?**

Comment: Does it work if you wrap it `(function() { const x = 'woo'; console.log(x); })();`?

Comment: What if you put it in a code block? `{ const x = 'woo'; console.log(x); }`?

Comment: @jared: works when wrapped

Comment: @evolutionxbox works in a block

Comment: I would never draw any hard conclusions from code tested in a console. Test things in an actual JS code file.

Comment: My guess would then be that it's related to how the developer console scopes lines of code. My *guess* is that each line is being scoped differently.

Comment: does the same happen if you use var for instance ? to check scoping and not a problem with const

Comment: @Gonzalo.- the console might scope differently based on declaration. `let` would be a truer test, `var` has no TDZ.

Comment: @zippydippy I wasn't actually trying to test `const`, I was doing some other work in the console (comparing some behavior in Chrome vs Edge) and const just broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the Edge console is using a `with` statement under its covers [like other implementations *did*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976785/1048572). This would explain `var`s and [even `function` declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419897/1048572) being hoisted outside into the global scope, but `let` and `const` will be locked into the block scope:

```
with (…) {
    const x = 'woo'
}
// next input:
with (…) {
    console.log(x) // obviously undeclared
}
```

Try entering them in multiline mode, in a single evaluation - there they should work.

But you also might want to file a bug, as the console is indeed expected to *feel* like evaluating things in the global scope.

Comment: The last comment on that answer you linked to pretty much says it all: "Few weeks ago we moved our console implementation in Chrome from with block to some symbol magic because with block blocked some ES6 features :)"

Comment: @JaredSmith Ha, perfect! Didn't bother to read it, I just wanted to link anything that showed the implementation approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out, but this is as much a guess as an answer. Too long for a comment though.

I *think* what's happening is that `const` and `let` [do not create](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#the-global-object) implicit globals when used in the top-level scope in the same way `var` does. Although top-level variables created with `const` and `let` are global, they are not properties of the global `window` object.

If the MS console is relying on that implicit `window` property creation for accessing variables created in the console, then `const` and `let` will not work.

I am unsure of the inner workings of Chrome Dev Tools, but it seems to create an anonymous function wrapper for code executed in the console:

```
throw new Error;
```

> VM679:1 Uncaught Error
>      at anonymous:1:7

```
(function() { throw new Error; })();
```

> VM759:1 Uncaught Error
>      at anonymous:1:21
>     at anonymous:1:33

I am unsure if there is other sandboxing going on here, I didn't necessarily find a lot of documentation on it.

Comment: "*If the MS console is relying on that implicit window property creation for accessing variables*" - why would it?

Comment: @Bergi IDK it sounds dumb to me too. As I said, speculation, but too long for a comment.

Comment: I posted my own speculation now :-)