# browser-inconsistent unexpected "undefined" string when using object destruction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, object-destruction

When I am trying out some object destruction syntax in some browser consoles, something unexpected happened.
Firstly I entered

```
action = {
      type: "SET_APPS_UI_REVERT",
      device: 23456,
      managedApps: "12345"
    }
```

and then

```
( { type, status, appsInfo, device,managedApps,appName } = action);
```

lastly

```
status
```

So both chrome and firefox decided to give me an `"undefined"` that is a string, rather than a undefined value, while edge would give me an usual `undefined`. However, when I typed

```
const { type, status, appsInfo, device,managedApps,appName } = action
```

and then

```
status
```

in edge, it gives me a `""` rather than `undefined`.

Is this results of some browser inconsistency? Or actually some bugs?

Screenshots are below

chrome-66-0-3359-181-no-const.PNG
[image: chrome-66-0-3359-181-no-const.PNG]

edge-41-16299-402-0-with-edgehtml-16-16299-no-const.PNG
[image: edge-41-16299-402-0-with-edgehtml-16-16299-no-const.PNG]

edge-41-16299-402-0-with-edgehtml-16-16299-with-const.PNG
[image: edge-41-16299-402-0-with-edgehtml-16-16299-with-const.PNG]

firefox-60-0-1-no-const.PNG
[image: firefox-60-0-1-no-const.PNG]

Comment: Don't forget [window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is a thing :) So in your first snipped you've actually assigned `undefined` to your window title, which when retrieved again is `"undefined"` so Chrome is definitely right. Does Edge support `const` in dev tools?

Comment: But your mdn page shows that `window.status` will not work in firefox, so I suppose that it won't be changed into text then?

Comment: But in edge, only status become empty string

Answer (score 0):

Using the following syntax:

```
( { type, status, appsInfo, device,managedApps,appName } = action);
```

You are explicitly saying "destructure `action.status` to the **existing** variable `status`.

If you don't already have a variable called `status` in the local scope then it will attempt to assign `action.status` to the [window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) property.  This property only accepts a string, so when `action` does not have a `status` property, you've effectively done this:

```
window.status = undefined;
```

Since `window.status` coerces to a string, when this is read back you get `window.status === "undefined";`.

Even though this doesn't have any *effect* on the statusbar in Firefox, it still exhibits the behaviour.

Your second part is expected behaviour also:

```
const { type, status, appsInfo, device,managedApps,appName } = action
```

Is different from before because you're declaring a **scoped** variable called `status`. This is where the browser differences come in. In Chrome, when you declare `const status` in devtools, the devtools is considered the "scope" and you can access it after it's declared. In Edge however, you can declare `const` within Dev Tools, but you can never access the value. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286729/const-doesnt-work-in-edge-15-developer-tools).

So in Edge, you get this kind of behaviour:

```
{
    const status = action.status;
    typeof status === "undefined"; // true
}
status; // The value of window.status. const status is out of scope
```