# Is using `with` statement with Proxies a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, with-statement, es6-proxy

**First of all,** I want to clarify, I know that **[`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is deprecated**, and using it **is** generally **a bad practice**.

However, my question is about a special case: using a special [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object as the parameter of [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

---

### Background

I'm working on a project, where I have to limit access of a piece of code to the global scope.

One approach might be to use a loop with `eval`, that creates constant variables with the value of `undefined` for each property of the global object, but that seems even worse than using `with`, and cannot limit access to variables created with `let` and `const`.

### The idea

The idea is to use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) as the argument of [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), whose...

- `has` trap always returns `true`, therefore it doesn't allow any lookups or assignments to go beyond the `with` statement
- `get` trap operates normally, except that it throws `ReferenceError`s when trying to access a non-existing variable (i.e. property)
- `set` trap operates normally (or maybe contains some custom logic)
- `target` object has no `[[Prototype]]` (i.e. it was created with `Object.create(null)`)
- `target` object has an [`@@unscopables`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/unscopables) property, with the value of an empty object, to allow scoping of every property

So, something like this code:

```js
const scope = Object.create(null)
Object.assign(scope, {
  undefined,
  console,
  String,
  Number,
  Boolean,
  Array,
  Object,
  /* etc. */
  [Symbol.unscopables]: Object.create(null)
})

const scopeProxy = new Proxy(scope, {
  get: (obj, prop) => {
    if (prop in obj)
      return obj[prop]
    else
      throw new ReferenceError(`${prop} is not defined`)
  },
  set: Reflect.set,
  has: () => true
})

with(scopeProxy) {
  //Sandboxed code
  
  foo = Number('42')
  console.log(foo) //42
  
  try{
    console.log(scopeProxy) //Inaccessible
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e) //ReferenceError: scopeProxy is not defined
  }
}
```

### Avoiding contras

There are several contras listed on the [MDN's page about the `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but this usage of it gets rid of each.

#### 1. Performance

- The problem:

  Looking up identifiers that aren't a member of `with` statement's parameter object is less performant.
- Avoidance:

  No lookups can go beyond the parameter object.

#### 2. Ambiguity

- The problem:

  It is hard to decide, which identifier gets looked up of those with the same name.
- Avoidance:

  All lookups and assignments retrieve or modify the property of the parameter object.

#### 3. Forward compatibility

- The problem:

  The properties of the parameter object or its prototype might change in the future.
- Avoidance:

  The parameter object is initially empty and has no prototype, therefore no properties can change.

### Question

The above code works perfectly, and the contras listed on MDN don't seem to apply to this case.

So, my question is:

**Is it still a bad practice to use the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement, and if so, what are the downsides of using it in this specific case?**

---

**Note:** I know that this approach in itself is not secure and can be bypassed. However, this question is limited only to whether it's considered bad for some reason to use the abovementioned `Proxy`-`with` combination. In this question, I'm not concerned about security (that's a related, but different question).

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is to run code inside a sandbox. Yes, a sandbox might use a proxy in its implementation, but you probably shouldn't write this yourself.

Comment: @Bergi I know, that a sandbox mechanism should be more complicated that this one, but my question is not really about whether this sandbox is safe and good, but instead if using `with` this way is bad or not.

Comment: Well, it still prevents you from using strict mode, and accessing properties through `with` and a proxy is still quite slow. I would try looking for a different solution to the underlying problem, but other than that you're just using `with` as a tool that seems to do what you need.

Comment: Btw, `({}.constructor.constructor('return alert')()('Unsafe global!'));` is not affected by the proxy at all.

Comment: @Bergi That's right, and I know about it,  but it's off-topic for this question. I'll edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the good old [lexical vs dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping) topic. In general lexical scope is more safe but in some situations dynamic scope makes sense, because it simplifies some solutions very much. I would say your example is one of the cases, where it may be useful.