# What is the best method to convert floating point to an integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, types

There are several different methods for converting floating point numbers to Integers in JavaScript. My question is what method gives the best performance, is most compatible, or is considered the best practice?

Here are a few methods that I know of:

```
var a = 2.5;
window.parseInt(a); // 2
Math.floor(a);      // 2
a | 0;              // 2
```

I'm sure there are others out there. Suggestions?

Comment: To everyone suggesting <code>parseInt</code>: read the original post again, carefully. <code>a</code> is a numeric variable, not a string.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [**this website**](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html#tcParseIn):

> parseInt is occasionally used as a means of turning a floating point number into an integer. It is very ill suited to that task because if its argument is of numeric type it will first be converted into a string and then parsed as a number...
>
> For rounding numbers to integers one of Math.round, Math.ceil and Math.floor are preferable...

Answer (score 10):

Apparently double bitwise-not is the fastest way to floor a number:

```
var x = 2.5;
console.log(~~x); // 2
```

Used to be an article here, getting a 404 now though: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/

<del>Google has it cached: `http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:wpZnhsbJGt0J:james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/+double+bitwise+not&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us`</del>

But the Wayback Machine saves the day! http://web.archive.org/web/20100422040551/http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/

Comment: Note: using bitwise operations one *must* keep a keen eye on the available numerical range (an error *often* made). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36131850/588079) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

From "Javascript: The Good Parts" from Douglas Crockford:

```
Number.prototype.integer = function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
}
```

Doing that your are adding a method to every Number object.

Then you can use it like that:

```
var x = 1.2, y = -1.2;

x.integer(); // 1
y.integer(); // -1

(-10 / 3).integer(); // -3
```

Comment: In ES6 this is what `Math.trunc()` does. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36131850/588079) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

The 'best' way *depends* on:

- rounding mode: what [type of rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) (of the float to integer) you expect/require
  for positive and/or negative numbers that have a fractional part.
  Common examples:

  ```
  float | trunc | floor |  ceil | near (half up)
  ------+-------+-------+-------+---------------
  +∞    |   +∞  |   +∞  |   +∞  |   +∞  
  +2.75 |   +2  |   +2  |   +3  |   +3
  +2.5  |   +2  |   +2  |   +3  |   +3
  +2.25 |   +2  |   +2  |   +3  |   +2
  +0    |   +0  |   +0  |   +0  |   +0
   NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN
  -0    |   -0  |   -0  |   -0  |   -0
  -2.25 |   -2  |   -3  |   -2  |   -2
  -2.5  |   -2  |   -3  |   -2  |   -2
  -2.75 |   -2  |   -3  |   -2  |   -3
  -∞    |   -∞  |   -∞  |   -∞  |   -∞
  ```

  For float to integer conversions we *commonly* expect **"truncation"**
  (aka **"round towards zero"** aka **"round away from infinity"**).
  Effectively this just 'chops off' the fractional part of a floating point number.
  Most techniques and (internally) built-in methods behave this way.
- input: how your (floating point) number is represented:

  - `String`
    Commonly radix/base: 10 (decimal)
  - floating point ('internal') `Number`
- output: what you want to do with the resulting value:

  - (intermediate) output `String` (default radix 10) (on screen)
  - perform further calculations on resulting value
- range:
  in what numerical range do you expect input/calculation-results
  and for which range do you expect corresponding 'correct' output.

Only *after* these considerations are answered we can think about appropriate method(s) and speed!

---

Per ECMAScript 262 spec: *all* numbers (type `Number`) in javascript are represented/stored in:
"[IEEE 754 Double Precision Floating Point (binary64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)" format.
So integers are *also* represented in the *same* floating point format (as numbers without a fraction).
<sup>Note: most implementations *do* use more efficient (for speed and memory-size) integer-types *internally* when possible!</sup>

As this format stores 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits and the first 53 significant bits ("mantissa"), we can say that: *only* `Number`-values *between* `-252` and `+252` can have a fraction.
In other words: *all* representable positive and negative `Number`-values *between* `252` to (almost) `2(211/2=1024)` (at which point the format calls it <strike>a day</strike> `Infinity`) are already integers (internally rounded, as there are no bits left to represent the remaining fractional and/or least significant integer digits).

And there is the first 'gotcha':
You can not control the internal rounding-mode of `Number`-results for the built-in Literal/String to float conversions (rounding-mode: IEEE 754-2008 "round to nearest, ties to even") and built-in arithmetic operations (rounding-mode: IEEE 754-2008 "round-to-nearest").
For example:
`252+0.25 = 4503599627370496.25` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370496`
`252+0.50 = 4503599627370496.50` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370496`
`252+0.75 = 4503599627370496.75` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370497`
`252+1.25 = 4503599627370497.25` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370497`
`252+1.50 = 4503599627370497.50` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370498`
`252+1.75 = 4503599627370497.75` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370498`
`252+2.50 = 4503599627370498.50` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370498`
`252+3.50 = 4503599627370499.50` is rounded and stored as: `4503599627370500`

To control rounding your `Number` needs a fractional part (and at least one bit to represent that), otherwise ceil/floor/trunc/near returns the integer you fed into it.

To correctly ceil/floor/trunc a Number up to x significant fractional decimal digit(s), we only care if the corresponding lowest and highest decimal fractional value will still give us a binary fractional value after rounding (so not being ceiled or floored to the next integer).
So, for example, if you expect 'correct' rounding (for ceil/floor/trunc) up to 1 significant fractional decimal digit (`x.1 to x.9`), we need *at least* 3 bits (not 4) to give us *a* binary fractional value:
`0.1` is closer to `1/(23=8)=0.125` than it is to `0` and `0.9` is closer to `1-1/(23=8)=0.875` than it is to `1`.

*only* up to `±2(53-3=50)` will all representable values have a non-zero binary fraction for no more than the *first* significant decimal fractional digit (values `x.1` to `x.9`).
For 2 decimals `±2(53-6=47)`, for 3 decimals `±2(53-9=44)`, for 4 decimals `±2(53-13=40)`, for 5 decimals `±2(53-16=37)`, for 6 decimals `±2(53-19=34)`, for 7 decimals `±2(53-23=30)`, for 8 decimals `±2(53-26=27)`, for 9 decimals `±2(53-29=24)`, for 10 decimals `±2(53-33=20)`, for 11 decimals `±2(53-36=17)`, etc..

A **"Safe Integer"** in javascript is an integer:

- that can be *exactly* represented as an IEEE-754 double precision number, and
- whose IEEE-754 representation *cannot* be the result of rounding any other integer to fit the IEEE-754 representation
  <sup>(even though `±253` (as an exact power of 2) can exactly be represented, it is *not* a safe integer because it could also have been `±(253+1)` before it was rounded to fit into the maximum of 53 most significant bits).</sup>

This effectively defines a subset range of (safely representable) integers *between* `-253` and `+253`:

- from: `-(253 - 1) = -9007199254740991` (inclusive)
  (a constant provided as static property [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.min_safe_integer) since ES6)
- to: `+(253 - 1) = +9007199254740991` (inclusive)
  (a constant provided as static property [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.max_safe_integer) since ES6)
  <sub>Trivial polyfill for these 2 new ES6 constants:</sub>

  ```
  Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER || (Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER=
    -(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER=9007199254740991) //Math.pow(2,53)-1
  );
  ```

Since ES6 there is also a complimentary static method [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.issafeinteger) which tests if the passed value is of type `Number` and is an integer within the safe integer range  (returning a boolean `true` or `false`).
<sup>Note: will also return `false` for: `NaN`, `Infinity` and obviously `String` (even if it represents a number).</sup>
Polyfill *example*:

```
Number.isSafeInteger || (Number.isSafeInteger = function(value){
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
                value === Math.floor(value) &&
                value  <   9007199254740992 &&
                value  >  -9007199254740992;
});
```

---

**[ECMAScript 2015 / ES6 provides a new static method `Math.trunc()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.trunc)

to truncate a float to an integer:**

> Returns the integral part of the number x, removing any fractional digits. If x is already an integer, the result is x.

Or put simpler ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)):

> Unlike other three Math methods: `Math.floor()`, `Math.ceil()` and `Math.round()`, the way `Math.trunc()` works is very simple and straightforward:
>   just truncate the dot and the digits behind it, no matter whether the argument is a positive number or a negative number.

We can further explain (and polyfill) `Math.trunc()` as such:

```
Math.trunc || (Math.trunc = function(n){
    return n < 0 ? Math.ceil(n) : Math.floor(n); 
});
```

<sup>Note, the above polyfill's payload can *potentially* be better pre-optimized by the engine compared to:

`Math[n < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](n);`</sup>

**Usage**: `Math.trunc(/* Number or String */)`
**Input**: (Integer or Floating Point) `Number` (but will happily try to convert a String to a Number)
**Output**: (Integer) `Number` (but will happily try to convert Number to String in a string-context)
**Range**: `-2^52` to `+2^52` (beyond this we should expect 'rounding-errors' (and at some point scientific/exponential notation) plain and simply because our `Number` input in IEEE 754 already lost fractional precision: since Numbers between `±2^52` to `±2^53` are already *internally rounded* integers (for example `4503599627370509.5` is internally already represented as `4503599627370510`) and beyond `±2^53` the integers also loose precision (powers of 2)).

---

**Float to integer conversion by subtracting the [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) (`%`) of a devision by `1`:**

Example: `result = n-n%1` (or `n-=n%1`)
This should also **truncate** floats. Since the Remainder operator has a higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than Subtraction we effectively get: `(n)-(n%1)`.
For positive Numbers it's easy to see that this floors the value: `(2.5) - (0.5) = 2`,
for negative Numbers this ceils the value: `(-2.5) - (-0.5) = -2` (because `--=+` so `(-2.5) + (0.5) = -2`).

Since the **input** and **output** are `Number` we *should* get the *same useful range and output* compared to ES6 `Math.trunc()` (or it's polyfill).
<sup>Note: tough I *fear* (not sure) there might be differences: because we are doing arithmetic (which internally uses rounding mode "nearTiesEven" (aka Banker's Rounding)) on the original Number (the float) and a second derived Number (the fraction) this seems to invite compounding digital_representation and arithmetic rounding errors, thus potentially returning a float after all..</sup>

---

**Float to integer conversion by (ab-)using [bitwise operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):**

This works by *internally* forcing a (floating point) `Number` conversion (truncation and overflow) to a signed 32-bit integer value (two's complement) *by using a bitwise operation* on a `Number` (and the result is converted back to a (floating point) `Number` which holds just the integer value).

Again, **input** and **output** is `Number` (and again silent conversion from String-input to Number and Number-output to String).

More important tough (and usually forgotten and not explained):
*depending on bitwise operation and the number's sign*, the *useful **range*** will be *limited* between:
`-2^31` to `+2^31` (like `~~num` or `num|0` or `num>>0`) *OR* `0` to `+2^32` (`num>>>0`).

This should be further clarified by the following lookup-table (containing *all* 'critical' examples):

```
              n             | n>>0 OR n<<0 OR   |    n>>>0    | n < 0 ? -(-n>>>0) : n>>>0
                            | n|0 OR n^0 OR ~~n |             |
                            | OR n&0xffffffff   |             |
----------------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------------
+4294967298.5 = (+2^32)+2.5 |             +2    |          +2 |          +2
+4294967297.5 = (+2^32)+1.5 |             +1    |          +1 |          +1
+4294967296.5 = (+2^32)+0.5 |              0    |           0 |           0
+4294967296   = (+2^32)     |              0    |           0 |           0
+4294967295.5 = (+2^32)-0.5 |             -1    | +4294967295 | +4294967295
+4294967294.5 = (+2^32)-1.5 |             -2    | +4294967294 | +4294967294
       etc...               |         etc...    |      etc... |      etc...
+2147483649.5 = (+2^31)+1.5 |    -2147483647    | +2147483649 | +2147483649
+2147483648.5 = (+2^31)+0.5 |    -2147483648    | +2147483648 | +2147483648
+2147483648   = (+2^31)     |    -2147483648    | +2147483648 | +2147483648
+2147483647.5 = (+2^31)-0.5 |    +2147483647    | +2147483647 | +2147483647
+2147483646.5 = (+2^31)-1.5 |    +2147483646    | +2147483646 | +2147483646
       etc...               |         etc...    |      etc... |      etc...
         +1.5               |             +1    |          +1 |          +1
         +0.5               |              0    |           0 |           0
          0                 |              0    |           0 |           0
         -0.5               |              0    |           0 |           0
         -1.5               |             -1    | +4294967295 |          -1
       etc...               |         etc...    |      etc... |      etc...
-2147483646.5 = (-2^31)+1.5 |    -2147483646    | +2147483650 | -2147483646
-2147483647.5 = (-2^31)+0.5 |    -2147483647    | +2147483649 | -2147483647
-2147483648   = (-2^31)     |    -2147483648    | +2147483648 | -2147483648
-2147483648.5 = (-2^31)-0.5 |    -2147483648    | +2147483648 | -2147483648
-2147483649.5 = (-2^31)-1.5 |    +2147483647    | +2147483647 | -2147483649
-2147483650.5 = (-2^31)-2.5 |    +2147483646    | +2147483646 | -2147483650
       etc...               |         etc...    |      etc... |      etc...
-4294967294.5 = (-2^32)+1.5 |             +2    |          +2 | -4294967294
-4294967295.5 = (-2^32)+0.5 |             +1    |          +1 | -4294967295
-4294967296   = (-2^32)     |              0    |           0 |           0
-4294967296.5 = (-2^32)-0.5 |              0    |           0 |           0
-4294967297.5 = (-2^32)-1.5 |             -1    | +4294967295 |          -1
-4294967298.5 = (-2^32)-2.5 |             -2    | +4294967294 |          -2
```

<sup>Note 1: the last column has extended range `0` to `-4294967295` using `(n < 0 ? -(-n>>>0) : n>>>0)`.

Note 2: bitwise introduces its own conversion-overhead(*s*) (severity vs `Math` depends on actual implementation, so bitwise *could* be faster (often on older historic browsers)).</sup>

---

Obviously, if your 'floating point' number was a `String` to begin with,
`parseInt(/*String*/, /*Radix*/)` would be an appropriate choice to parse it into a integer `Number`.
`parseInt()` will *truncate* as well (for positive and negative numbers).
The *range* is again limited to IEEE 754 double precision floating point as explained above for the `Math` method(s).

Finally, if you have a `String` and expect a `String` as output you could also chop of the radix point and fraction (which also gives you a larger accurate truncation range compared to IEEE 754 double precision floating point (`±2^52`))!

---

EXTRA:
From the info above you should now have all you need to know.

If for example you'd want **round away from zero** (aka **round towards infinity**) you could modify the `Math.trunc()` polyfill, for *example*:

```
Math.intToInf || (Math.intToInf = function(n){
    return n < 0 ? Math.floor(n) : Math.ceil(n); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer has already been given but just to be clear.

Use the Math library for this.  round, ceil or floor functions.

parseInt is for converting a string to an int which is not what is needed here

toFixed is for converting a float to a string also not what is needed here

Since the Math functions will not be doing any conversions to or from a string it will be faster than any of the other choices which are wrong anyway.

Comment: i argue that bitwise operations are much faster than Math ones, and should be used at all times instead of Math.floor and parseInt

Comment: @vsync:  I would argue that the intent of code should all times be clear and that clever performance tricks should only be used when proven necessary.

Comment: @vsync: using bitwise operations one *must* keep a keen eye on the available numerical range (an error *often* made). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36131850/588079) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Number(a).toFixed(0);

Or even just a.toFixed(0);

**Edit:**

That's rounding to 0 places, slightly different than truncating, and as someone else suggested, toFixed returns a string, not a raw integer. Useful for display purposes.

```
var num = 2.7;  // typeof num is "Number"
num.toFixed(0) == "3"
```

Comment: FYI: The Number constructor runs very slow, so you wouldn't want to use that one if performance was important.

Comment: Good to know! I edited to add the 2nd a.toFixed(0); form when I remembered javascript primitives still have functions.

Comment: Well, to be honest...they don't have methods. The interpreter first converts the primitive to a Number object, and then calls the method on it. This simply happens invisibly for you. So, your second example implicitly does the same as the first. :(

Comment: Not only that, but if a is 2.5, a.toFixed(0) rounds it up to 3.

Comment: That's by design. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp, but I'll edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = parseInt(n, 10);
```

If you don't specify a radix values like `'010'` will be treated as octal (and so the result will be `8` not `10`).

Comment: >>> parseInt(2e20)

200000000000000000000

>>> parseInt(2e21)

2

Answer (score 2):

Using bitwise operators. It may not be the clearest way of converting to an integer, but it works on any kind of datatype.

Suppose your function takes an argument `value`, and the function works in such a way that `value` must always be an integer (and 0 is accepted). Then any of the following will assign `value` as an integer:

```
value = ~~(value)
value = value | 0;
value = value & 0xFF;   // one byte; use this if you want to limit the integer to
                        // a predefined number of bits/bytes
```

The best part is that this works with strings (what you might get from a text input, etc) that are numbers `~~("123.45") === 123`. Any non numeric values result in `0`, ie,

```
~~(undefined) === 0
~~(NaN) === 0
~~("ABC") === 0
```

It does work with hexadecimal numbers as strings (with a `0x` prefix)

```
~~("0xAF") === 175
```

There is some type coercion involved, I suppose. I'll do some performance tests to compare these to `parseInt()` and `Math.floor()`, but I like having the extra convenience of no `Errors` being thrown and getting a `0` for non-numbers

Answer (score 2):

So I made a benchmark, on `Chrome` when the input is already a number, the fastest would be `~~num` and `num|0`, half speed: `Math.floor`, and the slowest would be `parseInt` see [here](http://jsperf.com/flooring-benchmark)

[image: benchmark result]

**EDIT**: it seems there are already another person who made [rounding](http://jsperf.com/truncating-decimals) benchmark (more result) and additional [ways](http://jsperf.com/dsafdgdfsaf/3): `num>>0` (as fast as `|0`) and `num - num%1` (sometimes fast)

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to be asking specifically about converting from a float to an int. My understanding is that the way to do this is to use `toFixed`. So...

```
var myFloat = 2.5;
var myInt = myFloat.toFixed(0);
```

Does anyone know if `Math.floor()` is more or less performant than `Number.toFixed()`?

Comment: important note: `.toFixed` the result is always `String`, `Math.floor` the result is always `Number`

Answer (score -1):

you could also do it this way:

```
var string = '1';
var integer = a * 1;
```

Comment: first, you have a typo ("a" should be "string"), and second, that just converts a string to a number, not an integer. Try changing the string to '1.1'.

Answer (score -4):

parseInt() is probably the best one. `a | 0` doesn't do what you really want (it just assigns 0 if a is an undefined or null value, which means an empty object or array passes the test), and Math.floor works by some type trickery (it basically calls parseInt() in the background).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean a || 0? A single | is a bitwise OR operator as far as I know, as opposed to the boolean OR operator. I'm not sure why it works, but try it in Firebug.

Comment: Yes, this is a bitwise operation.

Comment: Also, where do you get your information about how Math.floor works?

Comment: You're right, `a||0` is logical or. That means that `a|0` is working in the exact same manner as Math.floor. My info about Math.floor comes from digging into the internals of spidermonkey for various personal projects.

Comment: Oh, okay - so for that implementation, that is how Math.floor works, not necessarily every implementation.