# Math.round(num) vs num.toFixed(0) and browser inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Consider the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var num = i + 0.50;
   var output = num + " " + Math.round(num) + " " + num.toFixed(0);
   alert(output);
}
```

In Opera 9.63 I get:

> 0.5 1 **0**
>
> 1.5 2 2
>
> 2.5 3 **2**

In FF 3.03 I get:

> 0.5 1 **1**
>
> 1.5 2 2
>
> 2.5 3 **3**

In IE 7 I get:

> 0.5 1 **0**
>
> 1.5 2 2
>
> 2.5 3 **3**

Note the bolded results. Why are this inconsistencies present? Does this mean that `toFixed(0)` should be avoided? What's the correct way to round a number to the nearest integer?

Comment: FWIW IE6 output is identical to your IE7, and FF2(.0.0.20) is identical to your FF3, windows.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Opera 10 now.

Comment: Start with "i = -3" in the for loop and it gets worse! There are a lot of bad standards concerning rounding. For us programmers the best implementation is rounding ".5" towards the next even number (bankers rounding), the worst is rounding ".5" up, which is the standard of "Math.round" and as per today IE, Chrome and Opera follow it. What's the problem with it? Look at this: "(round(x*-1) + round(x))" does not necessarily result in 0 anymore. "num.toFixed" of all these browsers perform commercial rounding away from 0 which is okay for programmers and most understood by customers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Edit: To answer your edit, use `Math.round`.  You could also prototype the `Number` object to have it do your bidding if you prefer that syntax.

```
Number.prototype.round = function() {
  return Math.round(this);
}
var num = 3.5;
alert(num.round())
```

I've never used `Number.toFixed()` before (mostly because most JS libraries provide a [`toInt()`](http://mootools.net/docs/Native/Number#Number:toInt) method), but judging by your results I would say it would be more consistent to use the `Math` methods (`round`, `floor`, `ceil`) then `toFixed` if cross-browser consistency is what you are looking for.

Comment: It's also important to mention that Math.round is incredibly faster: `Math.round()` is almost 500% faster than `.toFixed` (https://jsperf.com/math-round-vs-tofixed2).

Comment: isn't it [bad practice](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) to modify native objects (i.e. `Number`)?

Comment: Yes; in most cases, modifying the native implementations is considered bad for many reasons, mostly dealing with obscurity and the resulting unexpected behaviors, especially for other or future team members. I recommend extending the object you wish to modify by either mixin functions/factories or by writing your own custom 'type' that points to an instance to (in this case) Number.prototype.

Answer (score 23):

To address your two *original* issues/questions:

### Math.round(num) vs num.toFixed(0)

The issue here lies in the misconception that these should always give the same result. They are, in fact, governed by different rules. Look at negative numbers, for example. Because [`Math.round`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15) uses ["round half up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) as the rule, you will see that `Math.round(-1.5)` evaluates to `-1` even though `Math.round(1.5)` evaluates to `2`.

`Number.prototype.toFixed`, on the other hand, uses what is basically equivalent to ["round half away from zero"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) as the rule, according to [step 6 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5), which essentially says to treat negatives as positive numbers, and then add back the negative sign at the end. Thus, `(-1.5).toFixed(0) === "-2"` and `(1.5).toFixed(0) === "2"` are true statements in all spec-compliant browsers. Note that these values are strings, not numbers. Note further that both `-1.5.toFixed(0)` and `-(1.5).toFixed(0)` are `=== -2` (the number) due to operator precedence.

### Browser inconsistencies

Most modern browsers—<strike>or at least the ones you might be expected to support at the time of this writing</strike> **[except for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169968/357774)**—should all implement the specs correctly. (According to [Renee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci#comment2034745_566564), the `toFixed` issue you pointed out in Opera has been fixed, presumably since they started using the same JS engine as Chrome.) It's still worth reiterating that, even if the specs were implemented consistently across all browsers, the behavior defined in the spec, particularly for `toFixed` rounding, can still be a bit unintuitive for "mere mortal" JS developers who expect true mathematical accuracy—see [Javascript toFixed Not Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10015027) and [this "works as intended" bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=522) that was filed on the V8 JS engine for examples.

### Conclusion

In short, these are two different functions with two different return types and two different sets of rules for rounding.

As others have suggested, I would also like to say "use whichever function fits your particular use case" (taking special care to note the peculiarities of `toFixed`, especially IE's errant implementation). <strike>I would personally lean more towards recommending some explicit combination of `Math.round/ceil/floor`, again, as others have mentioned.</strike> *Edit:* ...though, after going back and reading your clarification, your use case (rounding to a whole number) definitely calls for the aptly-named `Math.round` function.

Comment: Your Conclusion section, and the question it links to, seem to contradict the rest of your answer.

Comment: I clarified my conclusion and answer, which should agree with the linked question's top answers. `toFixed` isn't buggy, just very unintuitive.

Comment: Is the toFixed spec ambiguous? I'm trying to understand how different results between IE 11 and Chrome 42 is not a bug. On IE, 1.555.toFixed(2) yields "1.56" while on Chrome it yields "1.55". The top answer to the linked SO question starts out, "JavaScript's .toFixed() function is extremely buggy." The reason I'm taking the time to spell these out is because your statement, "the specs are implemented consistently across [modern] browsers," is either false or dangerously misleading.

Comment: You're absolutely right about IE, @pettys--I only tested with the values given by the OP. After playing with some other values, it seems to be the only browser (that I've tested) that does something different/wrong. Updated and clarified my answer again--thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I think FF is doing the right thing with toFixed, since step 10 below says "If there are two such n, pick the larger n."

And as [Grant Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254/) said: Use *Math.ceil(x)* or *Math.floor(x)* instead of *x.toFixed()*.

Everything below is from the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> ### 15.7.4.5 `Number.prototype.toFixed (fractionDigits)`
>
> Return a string containing the number represented in fixed-point
>   notation with `fractionDigits` digits after the decimal point. If
>   `fractionDigits` is undefined, `0` is assumed. Specifically, perform the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Let `f` be `ToInteger(fractionDigits)`. (If `fractionDigits` is undefined,
>      this step produces the value `0`).
> 2. If `f < 0` or `f > 20`, throw a `RangeError` exception.
> 3. Let `x` be this number value.
> 4. If `x` is `NaN`, return the string `"NaN"`.
> 5. Let `s` be the empty string.
> 6. If `x ≥ 0`, go to step 9.
> 7. Let s be `"-"`.
> 8. Let `x = –x`.
> 9. If `x ≥ 10^21`, let `m = ToString(x)` and go to step 20.
> 10. Let `n` be an integer for which the exact mathematical value of
>       `n ÷ 10^f – x` is as close to zero as possible. If there are two
>       such `n`, pick the larger `n`.
> 11. If `n = 0`, let `m` be the string `"0"`. Otherwise, let `m` be the
>       string consisting of the digits of the decimal representation
>       of `n` (in order, with no leading zeroes).
> 12. If `f = 0`, go to step 20.
> 13. Let `k` be the number of characters in `m`.
> 14. If `k > f`, go to step 18.
> 15. Let `z` be the string consisting of `f+1–k` occurrences of the
>       character `'0'`.
> 16. Let `m` be the concatenation of strings `z` and `m`.
> 17. Let `k = f + 1`.
> 18. Let `a` be the first `k–f` characters of `m`, and let `b` be the
>       remaining `f` characters of `m`.
> 19. Let `m` be the concatenation of the three strings `a`, `"."`, and `b`.
> 20. Return the concatenation of the strings `s` and `m`.
>
> The `length` property of the `toFixed` method is `1`.
>
> If the `toFixed` method is called with more than one argument, then the
>   behaviour is undefined (see section 15).
>
> An implementation is permitted to extend the behaviour of `toFixed` for
>   values of `fractionDigits` less than `0` or greater than `20`. In this case
>   `toFixed` would not necessarily throw `RangeError` for such values.
>
> **NOTE** The output of `toFixed` may be more precise than `toString` for
>   some values because `toString` only prints enough significant digits
>   to distinguish the number from adjacent number values. For example,
>   `(1000000000000000128).toString()` returns `"1000000000000000100"`, while
>   `(1000000000000000128).toFixed(0)` returns `"1000000000000000128"`.

Comment: Gosh, had those ecmascript people ever worked on standards before?: That standard is awfully written and is an entire class all unto itself: Literally I've never seen any standard even coming close to this mess. If possible please rewrite the quoted text instead of bulkloading that spaghetti onto the answer.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree @Pacerier. Do you happen to have examples of *good* specifications for reference?

Answer (score 6):

**toFixed()** returns a string value. From Javascript: The Definitive Guide

> Converts a number to a string that contains a specified number of
>   digits after the decimal place.

**Math.round()** returns an integer.

Clearly, toFixed() seem to be more use for money, for example,

> '$' + 12.34253.toFixed(2) = '$12.34'

It seems a big pity that **toFixed()** does not appear to round properly!

Comment: To be fair, there are multiple methods of rounding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `toFixed(0)` use `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()`, depending on what is required.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely seems that way, if you're getting inconsistent answers.

I can only guess that your intent with usin toFixed(0) is to turn a decimal number into an integer, at which point I recommend Math.floor().  There's a bit more discussion on the best way to do so in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131406/what-is-the-best-method-to-convert-to-an-integer-in-javascript).