# broken toFixed implementation

Tags: javascript

The default implementation of javascript's "Number.toFixed" appears to be a bit broken.

```
console.log((8.555).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.56
console.log((8.565).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.57
console.log((8.575).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.57
console.log((8.585).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.59
```

I need a rounding method that is more consistent than that.

In the range between 8.500 and 8.660 the following numbers don't round up correctly.

```
8.575
8.635
8.645
8.655
```

I've tried to fix the prototype implementation as follows, but it's only half way there. Can anyone suggest any change that would make it work more consistently?

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(decimalPlaces) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces || 0);
    var v = (Math.round(this * factor) / factor).toString();
    if (v.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
        return v + factor.toString().substr(v.length - v.indexOf('.'));
    }
    return v + '.' + factor.toString().substr(1);
};
```

Comment: I can imagine this is a floating point precision error.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-round0-vs-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-round0-vs-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistencies) similar?

Comment: It's probably related to floating point problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: I just tried your examples above on Chromium V12.0 and received the following results : 8.55 8.56 8.57 8.59. So your mileage may vary depending on your JavaScript implementation.

Comment: Why not to use Mozilla's implementation modified by [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L180)? It's a one-liner and was actually suggested in one of the answers.

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` rounding works. It could be used wherever num.isFixed() is used. see [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript/1726662#1726662)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of floating-point errors.

Compare `(8.575).toFixed(20)` with `(8.575).toFixed(3)` and imagine this proposition: `8.575 < real("8.575")`, where real is an imaginary function that creates a real number with infinite precision.

That is, **the original number is not as expected** and the inaccuracy has already been introduced.

One quick "workabout" I can think of is: Multiply by 1000 (or as appropriate), get the `toFixed(0)` of that (still has a limit, but it's absurd), then shove back in the decimal form.

Happy coding.

Comment: naturally, I can't use "toFixed" in my override of the same function. I had to stick to using "Math.round", but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Ty

Comment: @Joshua: Yes you can. Just store a copy of the  toFixed` in a variable, and `apply()` it to the number.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the answer pst. My implementation almost worked, but didn't in some cases because of floating point errors.

this line in my function is the culprit:
Math.round(this * factor)

(it's on the Number.prototype, so "this" is the number);
8.575 * 100 comes out to 857.4999999999999, which in turn rounds down.
this is corrected by changing the line to read as follows:
Math.round(Math.round(this * factor * 100) / 100)

My entire workaround is now changed to:

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(decimalPlaces) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces || 0);
    var v = (Math.round(Math.round(this * factor * 100) / 100) / factor).toString();
    if (v.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
        return v + factor.toString().substr(v.length - v.indexOf('.'));
    }
    return v + '.' + factor.toString().substr(1);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A consistent solution would be to add a fixed tolerance (epsilon) to each number before rounding. It should be small, but not too small.

For example, with an `eps = 1e-9`, this:

```
console.log((8.555).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.56
console.log((8.565).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.57
console.log((8.575).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.57
console.log((8.585).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.59
```

Becomes this:

```
console.log((8.555 + eps).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.56
console.log((8.565 + eps).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.57
console.log((8.575 + eps).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.58
console.log((8.585 + eps).toFixed(2));    // returns 8.59
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help someone, this is fixed popular formatMoney() function, but with correct roundings.

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
  var n = this,
  decPlaces = 2,
  decSeparator = ",",
  thouSeparator = " ",
  sign = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
  i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0)) + "",
  j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0,
  decimals = Number(Math.round(n +'e'+ decPlaces) +'e-'+ decPlaces).toFixed(decPlaces),
  result = sign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thouSeparator : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thouSeparator) + (decPlaces ? decSeparator + Math.abs(decimals-i).toFixed(decPlaces).slice(2) : "");
  return result;
};

(9.245).formatMoney(); // returns 9,25
(7.5).formatMoney();   // returns 7,50
(8.575).formatMoney(); // returns 8,58
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding/23560569#23560569)

```
function toFixed( num, precision ) {
    return (+(Math.round(+(num + 'e' + precision)) + 'e' + -precision)).toFixed(precision);
}
```