# round to 3 decimal points in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

How will i round margin_total to 3 decimal places?

```
margin_total = margin_total + parseFloat(marginObj.value);
document.getElementById('margin_total').value = margin_total;
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use [`num.toFixed(d)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to convert a number into the *String representation* of that number in *base 10* with *`d` digits* after the decimal point, in this case,

```
margin_total.toFixed(3);
```

Comment: You should also read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490687/broken-tofixed-implementation

Answer (score 21):

```js
const roundedDown = Math.round(6.426475 * 1000) / 1000
console.log(roundedDown) // 6.426

const roundedUp = Math.round(6.426575 * 1000) / 1000
console.log(roundedUp) // 6.427
```

The above code rounds to 3 decimal places (dp)

To round to 2 dp use 100 instead of 1000 (all occurrences)

To round to 4 dp use 10000 instead of 1000

You get the idea!

Or use this function:

```js
const round = (n, dp) => {
  const h = +('1'.padEnd(dp + 1, '0')) // 10 or 100 or 1000 or etc
  return Math.round(n * h) / h
}

console.log('round(2.3454, 3)', round(2.3454, 3)) // 2.345
console.log('round(2.3456, 3)', round(2.3456, 3)) // 2.346
console.log('round(2.3456, 2)', round(2.3456, 2)) // 2.35
```

Or just use [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash) [round](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#round) which has the same signature - for example, _.round(2.3456, 2)

Comment: Isn't this the only correct answer according to the question?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since toFixed method returns a String representation

Answer (score 10):

> The [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals. A string representation of input that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num = 5.56789;
  var n = num.toFixed(3)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the fixed number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const num = 70.012345678900
console.log(parseFloat(num.toFixed(3)));
// expected output: 70.012
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions so far produce the wrong result when rounding 1.015 to two decimal places (returns 1.01 instead of 1.02). Below is a function that will give the correct result no matter what the decimal place is, fixing the `toFixed()` rounding error.

```js
function roundTo(n, decimalPlaces) {
  return +(+(Math.round((n + 'e+' + decimalPlaces)) + 'e-' + decimalPlaces)).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
}

console.log(roundTo(1.015, 2));
```

Based on [this solution](https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/). [Learn more »](https://www.sitepoint.com/number-tofixed-rounding-errors-broken-but-fixable/)