# format currency in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, rounding

I'm doing some calculations on both client and server, and I've found a difference in the final result.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way for obtaining a 2 decimal float for representing currency.

Consider the following code (final number without format is 1,785):

**JS**

```
var sum = parseFloat(8.50);
var tax = parseFloat(21.00);
var total = parseFloat(sum * (tax / 100));
var test = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(test);
```

**PHP**

```
$sum = (float)"8.50";
$tax = (float)"21.00";
$total = (float)($sum * ($tax / 100));
$test = number_format($total, 2, ".", "");
echo $test;
```

In JS I get `1.78` and in PHP `1.79`

Comment: you should make the title a bit more clear. **format currency in PHP and JavaScript** suggests that you want a method which works with currencies, but in question you ask why different parsing/number formatting  methods return different results. consider changing the title to something like ***why does different PHP and JS format numbers differently***

Comment: if your question is only working with currencies/formatting currencies, @HorusKol gave you the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
var sum = parseFloat(8.50);
var tax = parseFloat(21.00);
var total = Math.round(sum*tax) / 100;
```

PHP

```
$sum = (float)"8.50";
$tax = (float)"21.00";
$total = round($sum*$tax/100, 2);
```

The mathematically correct rounding for 1.785 is 1.79 so the code above gives you what you want.

Comment: its not mathematically correct rounding, mathematically correct is 1.78

Comment: Do your research sir!

Comment: I know and just confirmed xD, 5 only updates the odd digits* on the left

Comment: common dude we are working with floats here. The convention you share is rounding 1.25 to 1, in the first example.

Comment: No need to argue. Just study your math. In this example it was the ceiling function. W/e learn also the notations

Comment: believe me I've studied my fair share of maths and Computer Science already.

Comment: well, ceiling and floor functions are only applicable to Real to Integers conversion. Rounding functions are more general, the take a float and return a float. in maths rounding function takes real and map to real, while ceil/floor takes Real and maps to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

[Possible duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490687/broken-tofixed-implementation)

You can use

```
function RoundNum(num, length) { 
    var number = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, length)) / Math.pow(10, length);
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not to use floats for storing and calculating currency values - use integers, with a resolution of 1/100 of a cent (or penny or whatever). Some financial applications go further - 1/10 000.

So, $1 is stored as 10 000 in your database.

After you have calculated taxes and totals, and rounded the result, then you can convert into a dollar amount for presentation.

```
var sum = 85000; // $8.50
var taxRate = 0.21; // 21%
var tax = sum * taxRate; // $1.785
console.log(Math.round(tax / 100) / 100); // $1.79

var cents = tax / 100; // 178.5 cents
var wholeCents = Math.round(cents); // 179 cents
var dollars = cents / 100; // $1.79
```

Comment: This is not answering my question at all

Comment: nice answer, I have seen this convention nearly in all the codebases that I have worked with. Seems like an industry wide convention.

Comment: @MatíasCánepa I'm trying to save you the headache of imprecise floating point representation when trying to work with precise currency calculations

Answer (score 0):

That's because PHP's number_format is rounding the numbers, if you don't want that, consider this function:

```
function numberFormatNotRound($n, $decs, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
{
    $decs ++;
    $n = number_format($n, $decs, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
    $n = substr($n, 0, -1);

    return $n;
}
```

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/457c-00nv