# Javascript Bug in toFixed(2) function?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Is there some kind of bug in the toFixed function in Javascript ?

```
6.075.toFixed(2) // = 6.08 (correct!)
8.075.toFixed(2) // = 8.07 (wrong!) should be 8.08 right ??
```

Am I missing something ?

Why is this, what's going on ? How can I get 8.075 to round correctly up to 8.08 ?

Thanks!

Comment: It does the rounding too, as it says on the tin: "rounding to nearest integer" - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Feels like floating point error. I'll read the duplicate target carefully to see if it's already covered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490687/broken-tofixed-implementation/37751946 has a (in my opinion) better answer.