# How do you round to one decimal place in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Can you round a number in JavaScript to one character after the decimal point (properly rounded)?

I tried the *10, round, /10, but it leaves two decimals at the end of the int.

Comment: `Math.round(n * 10) / 10` does work. What's your code?

Comment: FYI https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 1115, accepted):

`Math.round(num * 10) / 10` works, and here is an example...

```
var number = 12.3456789
var rounded = Math.round(number * 10) / 10
// rounded is 12.3
```

If you want it to have one decimal place, even when that would be a 0, then add...

```
var fixed = rounded.toFixed(1)
// 'fixed' is always to one decimal point
// NOTE: .toFixed() returns a string!

// To convert back to number format
parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))
// 12.34
// but that will not retain any trailing zeros

// So, just make sure it is the last step before output,
// and use a number format during calculations!
```

Using this principle, for reference, here is a handy little round function that takes precision...

```
function round(value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

... usage ...

```
round(12345.6789, 2) // 12345.68
round(12345.6789, 1) // 12345.7
```

... defaults to round to nearest whole number (precision 0) ...

```
round(12345.6789) // 12346
```

... and can be used to round to nearest 10 or 100, etc...

```
round(12345.6789, -1) // 12350
round(12345.6789, -2) // 12300
```

... and correct handling of negative numbers ...

```
round(-123.45, 1) // -123.4
round(123.45, 1) // 123.5
```

... and can be combined with toFixed to format consistently as string ...

```
round(456.7, 2).toFixed(2) // "456.70"
```

Comment: Be careful using `.toFixed()` as it returns a string when you maybe want a number.

Comment: Cool, obviously using `parseFloat` will remove decimals left by `.toFixed()` if it's a whole number (zeros). Generally, if you want to do the math it's best to follow your first example. If you want to display a number in your UI then use `.toFixed()`.

Comment: Hmmm... that makes sense, any way you convert to number must always strip the erroneous zeros, which is why it has to stay a string. I guess it should always be the last step before display, and not used in calculations.

Comment: Be careful using `.toFixed()` as it might return different rounding results for different browsers. Read [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci) for details on the topic!

Comment: Can I add a zero if no DP are present?

Answer (score 164):

```
var number = 123.456;

console.log(number.toFixed(1)); // should round to 123.5
```

Comment: Sometimes `toFixed()` has glitches - I have seen it in a Chrome browser where I call `toFixed()`, then convert to a string, and it shows something like `10.00000000068` - weird. Cannot reproduce this reliably though.

Comment: Yes, I accountered glitches with toFixed() even with just few decimals. It rounded fraction 4 to the next higher number instead of lower, if I recall correctly.

Comment: as mentioned by @cobby above: _be careful using `.toFixed()` as it returns a `String` when you maybe want a `Number`_

Answer (score 54):

If you use `Math.round(5.01)` you will get `5` instead of `5.0`.

If you use `toFixed` you run into [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding).

If you want the best of both worlds, combine the two:

```
(Math.round(5.01 * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)
```

You might want to create a function for this:

```
function roundedToFixed(input, digits){
  var rounder = Math.pow(10, digits);
  return (Math.round(input * rounder) / rounder).toFixed(digits);
}
```

Answer (score 43):

[Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash) has a `round` method:

```
_.round(4.006);
// => 4

_.round(4.006, 2);
// => 4.01

_.round(4060, -2);
// => 4100
```

[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#round).

[Source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L16425).

Comment: this is the best answer, but here I rewrote the lodash function

function precisionRound(number, precision) {
    number = Number(number);
    if (precision) {
        // Shift with exponential notation to avoid floating-point issues.
        let pair = (number.toString() + 'e').split('e');
        let value = Math.round(pair[0] + 'e' + (Number(pair[1]) + precision));

        pair = (value.toString() + 'e').split('e');
        return Number(pair[0] + 'e' + (Number(pair[1]) - precision));
    }
    return Math.round(number);
}

Answer (score 16):

You can simply do the following:

```
let n = 1.25
let result = Number(n).toFixed(1)
// output string: 1.3
```

Answer (score 12):

I vote for `toFixed()`, but, for the record, here's another way that uses bit shifting to cast the number to an int.  So, it always rounds towards zero (down for positive numbers, up for negatives).

```
var rounded = ((num * 10) << 0) * 0.1;
```

But hey, since there aren't any function calls, it's wicked fast. :)

And here's one that uses string matching:

```
var rounded = (num + '').replace(/(^.*?\d+)(\.\d)?.*/, '$1$2');
```

I don't recommend using the string variant, just saying.

Answer (score 10):

In general, decimal rounding is done by scaling: `round(num * p) / p`

**Naive implementation**

Using the following function with halfway numbers, you will get either the upper rounded value as expected, or the lower rounded value sometimes depending on the input.

This `inconsistency` in rounding may introduce hard to detect bugs in the client code.

```js
function naiveRound(num, decimalPlaces) {
    var p = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.round(num * p) / p;
}

console.log( naiveRound(1.245, 2) );  // 1.25 correct (rounded as expected)
console.log( naiveRound(1.255, 2) );  // 1.25 incorrect (should be 1.26)
```

**Better implementations**

By converting the number to a string in the **exponential notation**, positive numbers are rounded as expected.
But, be aware that negative numbers round differently than positive numbers.

In fact, it performs what is basically equivalent to ["round half up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) as the rule, you will see that `round(-1.005, 2)` evaluates to `-1` even though `round(1.005, 2)` evaluates to `1.01`. The [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#round) _.round method uses this technique.

```js
/**
 * Round half up ('round half towards positive infinity')
 * Uses exponential notation to avoid floating-point issues.
 * Negative numbers round differently than positive numbers.
 */
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    num = Math.round(num + "e" + decimalPlaces);
    return Number(num + "e" + -decimalPlaces);
}

// test rounding of half
console.log( round(0.5, 0) );  // 1
console.log( round(-0.5, 0) ); // 0

// testing edge cases
console.log( round(1.005, 2) );   // 1.01
console.log( round(2.175, 2) );   // 2.18
console.log( round(5.015, 2) );   // 5.02

console.log( round(-1.005, 2) );  // -1
console.log( round(-2.175, 2) );  // -2.17
console.log( round(-5.015, 2) );  // -5.01
```

If you want the usual behavior when rounding negative numbers, you would need to convert negative numbers to positive before calling [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), and then convert them back to negative numbers before returning.

```
// Round half away from zero
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    num = Math.round(Math.abs(num) + "e" + decimalPlaces) * Math.sign(num);
    return Number(num + "e" + -decimalPlaces);
}
```

There is a different purely mathematical technique to perform round-to-nearest (using ["round half away from zero"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)), in which **epsilon correction** is applied before calling the rounding function.

Simply, we add the smallest possible float value (= 1.0 ulp; unit in the last place) to the number before rounding. This moves to the next representable value after the number, away from zero.

```js
/**
 * Round half away from zero ('commercial' rounding)
 * Uses correction to offset floating-point inaccuracies.
 * Works symmetrically for positive and negative numbers.
 */
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    var p = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    var e = Number.EPSILON * num * p;
    return Math.round((num * p) + e) / p;
}

// test rounding of half
console.log( round(0.5, 0) );  // 1
console.log( round(-0.5, 0) ); // -1

// testing edge cases
console.log( round(1.005, 2) );  // 1.01
console.log( round(2.175, 2) );  // 2.18
console.log( round(5.015, 2) );  // 5.02

console.log( round(-1.005, 2) ); // -1.01
console.log( round(-2.175, 2) ); // -2.18
console.log( round(-5.015, 2) ); // -5.02
```

This is needed to offset the implicit [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) that may occur during encoding of decimal numbers, particularly those  having "5" in the last decimal position, like 1.005, 2.675 and 16.235. Actually, `1.005` in decimal system is encoded to `1.0049999999999999` in 64-bit binary float; while, `1234567.005` in decimal system is encoded to `1234567.0049999998882413` in 64-bit binary float.

It is worth noting that the maximum binary `round-off error` is dependent upon (1) the magnitude of the number and (2) the relative machine epsilon (2^-52).

Comment: This is an excellent writeup, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try with this:

```
var original = 28.453

// 1.- round "original" to two decimals
var result = Math.round (original * 100) / 100  // Returns 28.45

// 2.- round "original" to 1 decimal
var result = Math.round (original * 10) / 10  // Returns 28.5

// 3.- round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result = Math.round (8.111111 * 1000) / 1000  // Returns 8.111
```

It is less complicated and easier to implement...

With this, you can create a function to do:

```
function RoundAndFix (n, d) {
    var m = Math.pow (10, d);
    return Math.round (n * m) / m;
}
```

```js
function RoundAndFix (n, d) {
    var m = Math.pow (10, d);
    return Math.round (n * m) / m;
}
console.log (RoundAndFix(8.111111, 3));
```

See *[How to round using ROUND HALF UP. Rounding mode that most of us were taught in grade school](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730780/how-to-round-using-round-half-up-rounding-mode-that-most-of-us-were-taught-in-g)*.

Comment: Nope: RoundAndFix(1.005, 2) .

Comment: May require Ctrl + Shift + J to show the result (and allowing JavaScript from `stacksnippets.net`)

Answer (score 7):

Why not just

```
let myNumber = 213.27321;
+myNumber.toFixed(1); // => 213.3
```

1. [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):
   returns a string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.
2. [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()): The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already.

Answer (score 6):

```
var num = 34.7654;

num = Math.round(num * 10) / 10;

console.log(num); // Logs: 34.8
```

Answer (score 4):

To complete [Billy Moon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-one-decimal-place-in-javascript/33418071#33418071):

```
var round = function ( number, precision )
{
    precision = precision || 0;
    return parseFloat( parseFloat( number ).toFixed( precision ) );
}
```

The input parameter number may "not" always be a number, in this case .toFixed does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Using toPrecision method:

```
var a = 1.2345
a.toPrecision(2)

// result "1.2"
```

Comment: But you have to be careful because `12.345.toPrecision( 2 )` is `"12"`.

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish the rounding off task as:

```
var value = Math.round(234.567*100)/100
```

Will give you *234.56*.

Similarly

```
 var value = Math.round(234.567*10)/10
```

Will give *234.5*.

In this way, you can use a variable in the place of the constant as used above.

Answer (score 3):

ES 6 Version of Accepted Answer:

```
function round(value, precision) {
    const multiplier = 10 ** (precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made one that returns number type and also places decimals only if are needed (no 0 padding).

Examples:

```
roundWithMaxPrecision(11.234, 2); //11.23
roundWithMaxPrecision(11.234, 1); //11.2
roundWithMaxPrecision(11.234, 4); //11.23
roundWithMaxPrecision(11.234, -1); //10

roundWithMaxPrecision(4.2, 2); //4.2
roundWithMaxPrecision(4.88, 1); //4.9
```

The code:

```
function roundWithMaxPrecision (n, precision) {
    const precisionWithPow10 = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round(n * precisionWithPow10) / precisionWithPow10;
}
```

Comment: Not optimal. You calculate pow() twice with same params.

Answer (score 1):

A little Angular filter:

```
angular.module('filters').filter('decimalPlace', function() {
    return function(num, precision) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
        return Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
    };
});
```

Use it via:

```
{{model.value| decimalPlace}}
{{model.value| decimalPlace:1}}
{{model.value| decimalPlace:2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Number constructor, we can solve this problem:
For Example :

```js
const convertToCelsius = function(element) {
    return Number(((element -32 )/ 1.8 ).toFixed(1)) ;
};
```

This returns a number which was converted into a string due to `toFixed` method, then again converted to number via `number()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work reliably across anything I throw at it:

```
function round(val, multiplesOf) {
  var s = 1 / multiplesOf;
  var res = Math.ceil(val*s)/s;
  res = res < val ? res + multiplesOf: res;
  var afterZero = multiplesOf.toString().split(".")[1];
  return parseFloat(res.toFixed(afterZero ? afterZero.length : 0));
}
```

It rounds up, so you may need to modify it according to use case. This should work:

```
console.log(round(10.01, 1)); //outputs 11
console.log(round(10.01, 0.1)); //outputs 10.1
```

Comment: What about 100.65, 50.55, 100.05, 50.05, 1.005, and 1.05?

Comment: oh my... this is from more than 8 years ago and it seems I had implemented something spectacularly hacky, ouch. it does seem to work for the inputs you provided, not sure if you had any problems but I'd encourage anyone to use some other solution from here :) converting to string and splitting may not perform well when done in a hot loop

Answer (score 0):

If you care about proper rounding up then:

```
function roundNumericStrings(str , numOfDecPlacesRequired){ 
     var roundFactor = Math.pow(10, numOfDecPlacesRequired);  
     return (Math.round(parseFloat(str)*roundFactor)/roundFactor).toString();  }
```

---

Else if you don't then you already have a reply from previous posts

```
str.slice(0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round( num * 10) / 10` doesn't work.

For example, `1455581777.8-145558160.4` gives you `1310023617.3999999`.

So only use `num.toFixed(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to avoid the precision problems:

```
function badRound (num, precision) {
    const x = 10 ** precision;
    return Math.round(num * x) / x
}
// badRound(1.005, 2) --> 1

function round (num, precision) {
    const x = 10 ** (precision + 1);
    const y = 10 ** precision;
    return Math.round(Math.round(num * x) / 10) / y
}
// round(1.005, 2) --> 1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round( mul/count * 10 ) / 10

Math.round(Math.sqrt(sqD/y) * 10 ) / 10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function rnd(v,n=2) {
    return Math.round((v+Number.EPSILON)*Math.pow(10,n))/Math.pow(10,n)
}
```

this one catch the corner cases well

Answer (score 0):

If your source code is typescript you could use a function like this:

```
public static ToFixedRounded(decimalNumber: number, fractionDigits: number): number {
    var rounded = Math.pow(10, fractionDigits);
    return (Math.round(decimalNumber * rounded) / rounded).toFixed(fractionDigits) as unknown as number;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const solds = 136780000000; 
const number = (solds >= 1000000000 && solds < 1000000000000) ? { divisor: 1000000000, postfix: "B" }: (solds >= 1000000 && solds < 1000000000) ? { divisor: 1000000, postfix: "M" }: (solds >= 1000 && solds < 1000000) ? { divisor: 1000, postfix: "K" }: { divisor: 1, postfix: null }; 
const floor = Math.floor(solds / number.divisor).toLocaleString(); 
const firstDecimalIndex = solds.toLocaleString().charAt(floor.length+1); 
const final =firstDecimalIndex.match("0")? floor + number.postfix: floor + "." + firstDecimalIndex + number.postfix; 
console.log(final);
```

136780000000 --> 136.7B

1367800 --> 1.3M

1342 --> 1.3K