# Multiply variable to one decimal place

Tags: javascript

My employer wishes for a textbox to convert feet to metres to one decimal place, however, I am unfamiliar with Javascript and only know the bare basics for HTML purposes. My current code converts it correctly, but it is not to one decimal place.. Any suggestions?

*Code:*

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate() {
var ft = document.getElementById('LengthFt');
var res=0.3048*ft.value;
var mtrs = document.getElementById('LengthMtrs');
mtrs.value = res;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Try `var res=Math.round(0.3048*ft.value*10)/10;`

Comment: `res.toFixed(1)` will do it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript

Comment: Tip: we haven't needed to hide scripts with comments (!--) since 1996.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've done the conversion.  After that, all you need to do is format the number properly.

The [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method can be used to format to a fixed number of decimal places.

Replacing

```
mtrs.value = res;
```

with

```
mtrs.value = res.toFixed(1);
```

should leave the right number in the `LengthMtrs` input accurate to the closest decimeter.