# How to round using ROUND HALF UP. Rounding mode that most of us were taught in grade school

Tags: javascript, prototype

how to round using ROUND HALF UP in javascript?
I am using Prototype JavaScript framework version 1.5.1_rc3, so I prefer to use it if available. If not, I appreciate also if you share it.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain what rounding you want, there are different kinds. Many (most?) here likely didn't go to a "grade school" with the same curriculum you did so may or may not know what type of rounding you are referring to.

Answer (score 9):

The [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) will round up when `n >= 5` else round down

**Examples:**

```
Math.round(20.49);// 20

Math.round(20.5);// 21

Math.round(-20.5);// -20

Math.round(-20.51);// -21
```

<sub>**Note:** The examples were taken from the link above</sub>

Native functions don't bite, my advice is to try to always try to use them whenever possible. They are faster and do the same job after all

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
if (!Number.prototype.round) {
  Number.prototype.round = function() {
    return Math.round(this);
  }
}

var x = 5.49;
alert(x.round()); // 5
alert((7.499).round()); // 7
```

Comment: Number is a built–in constructor, adding a method to its prototype means that all numbers inherit the method. Number primitives are converted to Number objects during evaluation of expressions if the expression calls for it. So `5.49` is (more or less) converted to a Number as if `Number(5.49)` had been called, then its `round` method is called, passing the number object as `this`. All standard ECMAScript prototype inheritance. Note that the conversion is only for the sake of evaluating the expression, the value of `x` is still a number primitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundHalfUp(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}
```

reference : https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/round-in-javascript/