# Rounding calculated valued on JS

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive me for the stupid question but I'm a JS noob.

I created this the following code but can't get to round it (2 decimals).

Please help!

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Simple Calc</title>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
function combineder(){  
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);  
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
c=(a/452)/(b/100)
document.calculator.total.value=c;  
}  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="calculator">  
A: <input type="text" size="2"name="number1">   
<BR>  
B: <input type="text" name="number2">   
<BR>
<input type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick="javascript:combineder();">  
<br>
Your results is: $<input type="text" name="total">   

</form>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not use `javascript:etc...` in an `onclick` attribute, I think you are getting mixed up with the `href` attribute executing javascript as a url. Instead, you should simply have `onclick="combineder();"`

Secondly, you should use `var` to declare variables in the local scope, so they do not collide with other variables in the global namespace. Declare variables like this: `var c = 123;`

For your question, you can do this to round to 2 dp - which will not leave trailing 0s

```
// ...
var c=(a/452)/(b/100)
c = Math.round(c*100)/100
// ...
```

Or this, which will always leave trailing 0s and will be returned as a string representation of the number

```
// ...
var c=(a/452)/(b/100)
c = c.toFixed(2)
// ...
```

### Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343013/665261

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.toFixed()`. Here's an example

```
var myNum = 10.45621;
var newNum = myNum.toFixed(2);
```

Just pass the number of decimal places you wish to round to into the `.toFixed()` method.
Please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for more info in the `toFixed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has [number.toFixed( [digits] )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

You want two places so it would be

```
document.calculator.total.value=c.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
.toFixed(2);
```

to cut it to 2 decimals

or you can use

```
Math.round();
```

to round it.