# Javascript substracting numbers is not accurate - why

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/94wQJ/1/ - but probably someone can advise just by looking below.

```
<button type="button" id="allocate">Calc</button>

 $('#allocate').click(function () {
     val1 = 25.00;
     val2 = 16.37;
     val3 = val1-val2;
     alert(val3);
 });
```

25 - 16.37 = 8.63 - however, the alert for val3 = 8.62999999999

Why is it not accurate?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: some good info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: elaborate discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-javascript and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Using `toFixed` more [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

```
val3.toFixed(2)
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94wQJ/5/)

Comment: Thank you Ram, I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows.  Strange behaviour!!  Cheers, Mark

Comment: @MarkTait - It is not strange behaviour - It is due to the limitations (known) of floating point numbers

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it not accurate?

This is a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken), but to answer your specific question: floating point numbers generally store the number in base 2 because it allows storing more numbers more accurately than using base 10, at the expense of not being able to exactly store all base 10 numbers even with a small number of decimal places.

Comment: its not just Javascript's floating point math - it's floating point math in general unless you use things like specialised Decimal classes.

Comment: @sevenseacat: yes, agreed. You could go further and say that it is a limitation on how much information can you store in a particular number of bits, I can't quote which bit of information theory would apply though.

Answer (score 1):

Many decimal fractions not be represented exactly in binary.

Use `.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

val3 = Math.round(val3*100)/100;

`I have update here http://jsfiddle.net/94wQJ/7/`