# How to check if a number has two decimal places and keep the trailing zero if necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have these numbers:

- 2
- 2.05
- 2.547
- 2.5

How can I do a check to see if the number has two decimal places?

If it has 2 decimals, how do you drop the second decimal number (rounding) but keep the trailing 0 if needed?

Examples of results:

```
2.05 would end in 2.1
2.04 would end in 2.0
2.54 would end in 2.5
```

I realise you can use toFixed(1), but that converts it to a string. And if you convert it to a int with parseInt(), it loses the trailing zero

Thanks guys

Comment: 1. round 2. format as necessary

Comment: use `.toFixed`, it rounds the float to the number of decimal places specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Comment: but toFixed turns it into a string, and if you use parseInt it gets rid of the trailing zero

Comment: This is not a duplicate to that question...

Comment: it would have to be a string you cant have a float that keeps the trailing 0 as trailing 0's are meaning less in floats which is why they are always dropped.

Comment: Ah I see.. That would explain a lot :)

Comment: why would you use parseInt, you should be using parseFloat. parseInt parses a string to an integer, and integers have no decimal parts. Even then `2.0` would still be parsed to `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but toFixed turns it into a string, and if you use parseInt it gets rid of the trailing zero

You can have a number or you can have a representation of a number, but there is no third alternative.

If you want a representation of a number, what's wrong with a string? If you want a number, then there is no "trailing zero".

The **number** represented by "2.0" doesn't have a trailing zero because only representations can have trailing zeros. The number two can be represented with or without a trailing zero and it's the same number.

So: Do you want a number or a representation?

I think you must want a representation, because really only representation can have some specific number of decimal places. In that case, why isn't `toString` the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `x` is the value you are dealing with

```
var temp = Math.round(x * 10) / 10;   // This is the value as a number
document.write(temp.toFixed(1));      // writes the number in the desired format
```

In JavaScript, there is no distinction between the value `1.5` and the value `1.50` - as numbers, they are exactly the same. It is only when you convert them to a string, using something like `toFixed()`, that they become distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (the HTML upon which this is based follows):

```
$('li').text(function(i,t){
    var rounded = t.split('.')[1] ? (Math.round(parseFloat(t) * 10)/10).toFixed(1) : t;
    return t + ' (' + rounded + ')';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZywEt/).

The ternary:

```
t.split('.')[1] ? (Math.round(parseFloat(t) * 10)/10).toFixed(1) : t;
```

Assesses whether there's a period, if so then we parse the float to a number, multiply it by 10 (because we want the number to one decimal place), round that number and then divide it by ten and then, with `toFixed(1)` truncate the number to one (correctly-rounded) decimal place.

If there's no decimal portion to the number (it's an integer, not a float) we do nothing with it and simply use the existing number as it was found.

This is based upon the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2.05</li>
    <li>2.547</li>
    <li>2.5</li>
    <li>2.04</li>
</ul>
```