# Not able to keep trailing zero's in decimal after conversion to float in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert string to float in angular, but when I use **parseFloat** it is removing zero's from decimal. How can I keep these zero's with the values. Below example will help you to understand more

ex: My value is b="12.00" and I am trying to convert it to float using below syntax.

```
   abc = parseFloat(b.toFixed(2))
```

**Current Output : 12**

**Expected Output : 12.00**

Comment: This is how numbers work in JavaScript, unnecessary decimals are removed. But I really don't get why this is important to you. `12.00` and `12` are the same number, you can try `12 === 12.00`, it will return `true`.

Comment: If you want to keep the trailing zeroes for display purposes then you need to convert the number to a string and apply some formatting. If I said I had 12.00 apples you would understand that as I had exactly 12 apples - 12 and 12.00 are exactly the same number. A number does not have a format, that's what strings are for.

Comment: Also, JavaScript only has a single [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) type used for all numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a number has two decimal places and keep the trailing zero if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192454/how-to-check-if-a-number-has-two-decimal-places-and-keep-the-trailing-zero-if-ne)

Comment: @phuzi No, the url which you shared is not helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Angular, what you code essentially does is this -

```
const b = "12.00";
const abc = parseFloat(b);
```

From [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) -

> The toFixed() method formats a **number** using fixed-point notation.

This method returns a string with fixed-point notation.
You have mentioned that you have the value "12.00" assigned to `b`, if this is a string value then you need to parse it before calling `toFixed()` like below -

```
const b = "12.00";
const parsedNum = Number.parseFloat("12.00");
const abc = parsedNum.toFixed(2); // This is essentially the same as the initial value of "b" i.e. "12.00", see if you really want to do this.
```

If it's a number, then just call the `toFixed()` like below -

```
const c = 12.00;
const abc = c.toFixed(2); // "12.00"
```

Also, go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057489/javascript-convert-int-to-float) question.