# Why is this code not rounding numbers properly

Tags: javascript

```
var money = prompt("Enter an amount of money");
money = parseFloat(money);
var months = prompt("Enter how long you will be investing for in months");
months = parseInt(months);
months = Math.round(months);
var interest = prompt("Enter an interest rate you would like to test your investment at");
interest = parseFloat(interest);
console.log(months);
```

Why does this code round down the months no matter what? What do i have to do differently?

Comment: Because you truncate the months when you say `parseInt(months)`?

Comment: Duplicate, there's lots of answers about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript/7343013#7343013

Comment: RTFM - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt.  "parseInt truncates numbers to integer values."

Comment: @j08691 don't say "RTFM", it's rude

Comment: @jcollum Sounds like he might have read 1 to many questions of this nature for the day.

Comment: @jcollum: This isn't a duplicate of the question you linked.  This isn't actually about rounding to anything but whole numbers.

Comment: @jcollum - doesn't the "f" mean "fantastic"?

Comment: Yeah not a dupe of that question, but there's soooo many rounding questions on here that it must be a dupe of one of them

Comment: @j08691 Hah, you know it doesn't. I think what this guy really needs is to learn how to debug his js. Stepping through the code and adding some watches would've solved this quickly.

Comment: What's odd is that he *used* `parseFloat` in other locations - apparently without knowing the difference.

Comment: @j08691 Im new to javascript so i dont really know how to debug, i kind of understand the consoles in web browsers, but what are the "watches" i could've added?

Answer (score 2):

The function `parseInt` converts the number to an integer, which doesn't support fractional numbers (decimals).

```
months = parseInt(months);
months = Math.round(months);
```

Use `parseFloat` here instead:

```
months = parseFloat(months);
months = Math.round(months);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to round the int in the first place? It should always be a whole number, right?

That said, never use `parseInt` without also specifying the radix, which in your case should be 10.

```
months = parseInt(months, 10);
```

Comment: I was a bit thrown by that at first as well, but it seems that he must be allowing for a fractional months to be input. Only way this question makes sense. Strange.

Comment: `Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.`