# Bug add negative numbers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, parsefloat

I have a problem with add negative numbers jquery,
code:

```
var k = parseFloat(-0.1) + parseFloat(0.3);
console.log(k); // 0.19999999999999998
```

but i need results 0.2

Comment: Also see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how computer's parse numbers, specifically the floating point representation. 0.1 is 1/10 which cannot be exactly represented by a number of base 2 (i.e. 2^n).

If you can accept some rounding error I would refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343013/1106659), and do something like this:

```
var k = parseFloat(-0.1) + parseFloat(0.3);

k = Math.round(k * 100) / 100; // 2 decimal points precision. Use 10 instead of 100 for 1 decimal point precision.
console.log(k); // 0.2 :)
```

Hope this helps.