# get an array value using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, something like this:

```
var details=[{month:  1, equips:32.1, instals:12.6, softs:  6.7, manuts:6.2,  formacs:  9.7, total:0.0},    {mes:  2,       equips:37.5, instals:14.1, softs:  7.5, manuts:5.7,  formacs:  8.7, total:0.0}];
```

And to aid me I created a new array "headers" that get the objects headers, something like this function that creates the array I want:

```
var headers=[]
function getHeaders(){
                var i,cab;
                for(cab in details[0]) headers.push(cab);
            }
```

And I get an array, something like this `headers=[month, equips, instals, softs, manuts, formacs, total]`, and it is working, because if I call, for instance, headers[2] I get "instals".

My may goal was to call something from "details" array with something like this:

`details[0].headers[2]` and get the value : 12.6 instead of using `details[0].instals`

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use brackets instead of dot notation.

like so: `details[0][headers[2]]`

Comment: Thank you (obrigada)... it worked ... btw , i need to change the value so that i get only one decimal ... and i tried ( i and j are part of a "for" cycle)

[details[i][headers[j]].toFixed(1), but i get "this is not a function"...

Comment: de nada :)
This question might help with the rounding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript

Comment: yep, that worked, thx... actually what i did was correct, but i'ved forgot that my first value was a text and not a number, so it was getting a "not a function" because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly get the value using:

```
Object.values(details[0])[0];//1 (month)
```