# Why multiply Math.round input say by 1000 and then divide result?

Tags: javascript

A function to convert from temperatures is written below

```
function tryConvert(temperature, convert /*callback*/) {
  const input = parseFloat(temperature);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
    return '';
  }
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}
```

My question is this line:

```
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
```

Why the need to multiply by 1000? and also divide result by 1000?

Comment: This rounds to three decimal places

Comment: @JaredGoguen Can  you elaborate? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If you have `0.12345` then it will do `Math.round(123.45 )` - > `123` then divide by `1000` -> `0.123`. The method rounds to three decimal places

Comment: More or less the same as  `return convert(input).toFixed(3)`

Comment: The code *attempts* to round to three decimal places, but due to the behavior of binary floating point math the result may have non-zero decimal digits beyond the third fractional digit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Multiplying by 1000 moves the decimal point 3 digits to the right.
5.333333 = > 5333.333

Rounding rounds to whole integers. (Only zeros after decimal point)
5333.333 = > 5333.000

After that dividing by 1000 moves the decimal point back to where it started.
5333.000 = > 5.333000

The result is, that the number is rounded to 3 digits after the decimal point.
5.333333 = > 5.333000

Answer (score 0):

Is to round up the `output` to 3 decimals:

Example:

```js
const rounded = Math.round(1.23456 * 1000) / 1000; // = 1.235
console.log(rounded);
```