# How would I round a number (eg: 2.12) to the nearest tenth (2.1) in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this but is all I have found is rounding to the nearest whole number. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with math.round or if there is a different solution. Thanks!

Comment: please add some more use cases and what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: I have looked around quite a bit and not found anything, the link that you sent dosn't work in my case because i want it rounded to the tenth, not 100th.

Comment: @TechHax _“because I want it rounded to the tenth, not 100th”_ — but hopefully you understand the solutions given in the answers and can easily adjust them, right? We don’t need a new question for every possible rounding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Method 1:** The quick way is to use `toFixed()` method like this:

```
var num = 2.12;
var round = num.toFixed(1); // will out put 2.1 of type String
```

One thing to note here is that it would round `2.12` to `2.1` and `2.15` to `2.2`

**Method 2:** On the other hand you can use `Math.round` with this trick:

```
var num = 2.15;
Math.round(num * 10) / 10; // would out put 2.2
```

It would round to the upper bound.

So, choose whichever you like.

Also if you use a modern version of JS ie. ES then using `const` and `let` instead for variable declaration might be a better approach.

**NOTE:** remember that .toFixed() returns a string. If you want a number, use the Math.round() approach. Thanks for the reminder @pandubear

Comment: _“One thing to note here that it would round `2.15` to `2.1` and `2.15` to `2.2`.”_ — only at most one of these is true. You probably also want to explain why this is; there exist [different rounding methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/977796/4642212).

Comment: Worth warning that .toFixed() returns a string. If you want a number, use the Math.round() approach.

Answer (score 6):

```
Math.round(X);           // round X to an integer
Math.round(10*X)/10;     // round X to tenths
Math.round(100*X)/100;   // round X to hundredths
Math.round(1000*X)/1000; // round X to thousandths
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.