# how to round the decimal number to the nearest tenth in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal

I'm a beginner to Javascript I,m trying to creat calories calculator
but the result is always  decimal  number like this ( 2758.59375)
I want to know how to round it to nearest tenth like ( 2758.6)
and thank you
That is my code
if it was necessary

```
var
weight = prompt ("enter your weight in kg ");
height = prompt ("enter your height in cm");
age = prompt ("enter your age");
train = prompt ("how many days you train per week");
calories=(weight*10 )+(height*6.25)-(age *5) +5;
low = 1.25;
med = 1.375;
high = 1.505;
veryhigh = 1.725;
if(train >=0)
{
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="calories  you need is: " +calories * low + " calcalorie" ;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `2758.59375` rounded to the nearest tenth be `2758.6`?

Comment: You could try `Math.round(calories * low * 10) / 10`

Comment: It seems you want to fix to decimal place? you can use calories.toFixed(1) method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually want a number like 2758.59375 to round down to 2758.5? I would expect that number to be rounded to 2758.6, personally. Depending if you want it to round down, round up, or round to nearest, the code is slightly different.

The simplest way is to say:

```
> var num = 2758.59375
> num.toFixed(1)
2758.6
```