# How do you round down to one decimal, even if it ends with a 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a product page that is fetching products information and displaying the products on the page. The API returns three price points. I have to add them up and display the price rounded down to one decimal. I have a solution already working, but it only works if it's not a whole number.

`22.7312` returns `22.7`, but `22.0` returns `22`. I would like to always show one decimal, even if it's a zero. This is my current solution. How can I change it so that it shows the one decimal, even if it's a zero?

```
Math.floor(
    (parseFloat(product.price1['regionalPrice'])
      + parseFloat(product.price2['marketPrice'])
      + parseFloat(product.price3['localPrice'])
    ) * 10) / 10
```

Comment: You're confusing _rounding_ with _formatting_. Numbers, in every programming language, do not have trailing zeroes - that's just mathematics. What you're looking at in your debugger or output is the _default formatting_. Specify a different format to retain N-many trailing decimal places.

Comment: Look into `.toFixed(1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your float result with the .toFixed(x) method.

Here is a full code sample for this:

```
const p1 = parseFloat(product.price1['regionalPrice']);
const p2 = parseFloat(product.price2['marketPrice']);
const p3 = parseFloat(product.price3['localPrice']);

const price = Math.floor((p1 + p2 + p3) * 10) / 10;
const displayPrice = price.toFixed(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try rounding your numbers with the number.toFixed() function where you pass 1 as a function argument.
I tried it and
`num = 22;                                                                                   num = nums.toFixed(1);                                                        console.log(num)`
prints out 22.0.
Hope that this is what you were looking for ^^