# How to iterate through this array applying a decimal increase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have a list which has an Id column. When a user adds an item it starts with 3.1, and continues 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 as each item is added.

The problem: If a user deletes for e.g. 3.3 in a list of up to 3.7, the order of these Id's won't be sequential. I'm attempting with the below to iterate through the Id's to reorder them, starting with 3.1 for top row of the list.

Here's the delete function:

```
 const deleteItem = () => {
        const currentArray = myArr;
        for (var i = 0; i < currentArray .length; i++) {
  
            if (currentArray [i] == selectedItem) {
                currentArray .splice(i, 1);
            }
            setMyArr([...currentArray ]);
        }
          for(var i = 3.1; i < currentArray .length; i++){
        i + 0.1;
            
          }
    };
```

The first `for`, deletes the item and sets the array of items, the second `for` is my attempt to reset the order of the Ids.

I have looked at several solution on SO but not found them useful.

How would I do this.

Comment: Beware of [floating point imprecisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Yes - I've encountered that, I resolved in the past by using:
Math.round((Math.max(...currentIds) + 0.1) * 100) / 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array indexes and length will not work with decimal values.

What I think you want to do is to iterate the array and set the id based on the id of the first one:

```
const finalArray = currentArray.map((item,index)=> ({...item, id:3.1 + index * 0.1});
```

as noted in comments to the question `index * 0.1` is subject to rounding errors, so you should apply your roundings.

(I'm assuming your items are objects and have an id attribute)

Comment: This works, thanks - cheeky question. I can't seem to figure out how to round the result to avoid the rounding errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript

Comment: But which part of your line you gave do I need to wrap?

Comment: `({...item, id: round(3.1 + index * 0.1, 1)});` using the round function from the link

Comment: `id: (31+i)/10 ` also works fine

Comment: Neither of those rounds work @Tiago.

Comment: const finalArray = currentArray.map((item,index) => ({...item, Id:(31+i)/10 + index * 0.1})); - not working. It's also breaking the re-ordering.

Comment: const finalArray = currentArray.map((item,index) => ({...item, Id:(31+index)/10 }));

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the item you want to delete, and then set again the ids like this:

```
currentArray
  .filter(item => item !== selectedItem) // Remove the selectedItem from the array
  .map((item, idx) =>({...item, id:3.1 + index * 0.1}) // Reset the ids sequentially
```