# how to get 1.450 = 1.5 in javascript? (round to 1 decimal place)

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

My Value is 1.450 and I have to round it to 1 decimal place.

I want 1.450 = 1.5 in Javascript can any body fix this please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need this:

```
var mynum = 1.450,
  rounded = Math.round(mynum * 10) / 10;
```

Answer (score 4):

suppose you have

```
var original=28.453;
```

Then

```
var result=Math.round(original*10)/10  //returns 28.5
```

From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

You can also see [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Given your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEtAC/12/), the simplest change would be:

```
result = sub.toFixed(1) + "M";
```

to:

```
result = Math.ceil(sub.toFixed(1)) + "M";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Math.round` then you will get `1` for `1.01`, and not `1.0`.

If you use `toFixed` you run into [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding).

If you want the best of both worlds combine the two:

```
(Math.round(1.01 * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)
```

You might want to create a function for this:

```
function roundedToFixed(_float, _digits){
  var rounder = Math.pow(10, _digits);
  return (Math.round(_float * rounder) / rounder).toFixed(_digits);
}
```