# Rounding a number to one decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you round to 1 decimal place in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript)

The following code, displays the total distance covered, on a particular route, displayed on google maps. I managed to convert the number from kilometers to miles. Here is the code for the function:

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = total *0.621371/ 1000.
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' mi';
```

The total is displayed as `41.76483039399999 mi`. How would round off the `total` to one decimal place?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

    var n = 123.123;
    n.toFixed(1); // 123.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var total = 41.76483039399999;
total = total.toFixed(1) // 41.8
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsLp6/

Comment: Be careful using `.toFixed()` as it might return different rounding results for different browsers. Read [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci) for details on the topic!

Comment: I want to do it, but with a high value: example
749,640
now i expected: 750,000
how can i do it ?

Comment: i want to make 41.78 to 41.7 not 41.8 !!

Comment: @MojtabaDarzi - For that you'll need `Math.floor()`, with multiplication and division for your precision: `Math.floor(41.78 * 10) / 10` will return `41.7`.

Answer (score 15):

```
Math.round(total * 10) / 10
```

This results in a number. toFixed() gives a string, as detailed in other answers.

Comment: maybe because there's a built-in function for it (`.toFixed()`) which is more elegant than using Math.round(). Though there's nothing wrong with your solution and it shouldn't be down voted because technically it is not wrong.

Comment: @AlexStack The two different ways return different types - mine is numerical, toFixed() returns a String.

Comment: Good point. +1 for that from me.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed); `41.76483039399999.toFixed(1) === "41.8";`

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0, myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = (total * 0.621371 / 1000).toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' mi';
}
```

There are a very many other ways to achieve this, for example, without using any methods from `Math` or instances of `Number`

```
(~~(10 * total) + (~~(100 * total) % 10 >= 5))/10 + '' // "41.8"
// (      417   +     (6 >= 5)               )/10 = 41.8
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do what you want:

var total = 41.76483039399999;
print(x.toFixed(2));

It will be printed 41.76