# Rounding in Javascript to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list and it has values which are to 2 decimal places.

```
<label for="delivery">Delivery:</label>
<select id="delivery" name="delivery">
    <option value="1.50">Fast</option>
    <option value="2.50">Medium</option>
    <option value="3.50">Slow</option>
</select>
```

How can I call this in Javascript, I know I have to use the toFixed(2) somewhere in the line below, but I'm unsure where to put it.

```
var delivery = parseInt($('#delivery').val());
```

Also, would I put it in the div in where it is outputted or in the calculation, or both?

Jonah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `parseInt()` (as it kills the decimals). Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) then [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
 var delivery = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()).toFixed(2);
```

**Note:** If you are interested in rounds with `toFixed()`, reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var delivery = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var delivery = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()).toFixed(2);
```