# Decimal rounding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, rounding

I am trying to achieve what was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251659/rounding-in-javascript-to-2-decimal-places). In most scenarios, it is working fine by using the following code:

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

But I encountered a situation where it fails due to a very odd behavior. The number I'm trying to round is 1.275. I am expecting this to be rounded to 1.28, but it is being rounded to 1.27. The reason behind this is the fact that num * 100 is resulting in 127.49999999999999 instead of 127.5.

Why is this happening and is there a way around it?

**EDIT**

Yes, this question is probably the root cause of the issue I'm facing, but the suggested solutions of the selected answer are not working for me. The desired end result is a rounded number that is displayed correctly. So basically I'm trying to achieve what that question is instructing (check below) but I cannot figure out how.

> If you just don’t want to see all those extra decimal places: simply
>   format your result rounded to a fixed number of decimal places when
>   displaying it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: see this too https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to ensure the precision that you're looking for:

```
var x = 1.275;
var y = x * 100;
y = y.toFixed(1); // y = 127.5
```

Comment: Then use `y = y.toFixed(2);`