# How to calculate percentage of not equal number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate percentage of some not equal number. I am counting percentage using `parseFloat`, but it's work only for rounded numbers like 2000, or 200 which gives me 20% and 2%. I's not working for 2200 or 220 to reach 2.2% or 22.2%.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.js-baOfferPrice.percentage', function(e) {
    var s, target = $(e.target);
    var p = $('.js-baAppPrice').text();

    s = parseFloat(parseInt(target.val(), 10) * 100) / parseInt(p, 10);

    target.val() === "" ? target.val("") : target.val(Math.round(s).toFixed(0));
});
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Percentage of What? Can you post your HTML

Comment: Do you not need to change your .toFixed(0) to .toFixed(1)?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? I don't quite understand the problem you are describing.

Comment: Don't call `round()`. That removes the fraction.

Comment: The last is gratuitous use of the `?:` operator, consider: `if (target.val() != ""){...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `Math.round(s)`, since that removes the fractional part of the number. Just use `toFixed`, and specify the number of decimal places there. It will round that digit.

```
if (target.val() !== "") {
    s = parseFloat(parseInt(target.val(), 10) * 100) / parseInt(p, 10);
    target.val(s.toFixed(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `.toFixed(0)` to `.toFixed(1)` and remove the `Math.round()`

This line:

```
target.val() === "" ? target.val("") : target.val(Math.round(s).toFixed(0));
```

will become:

```
target.val() === "" ? target.val("") : target.val(s.toFixed(1));
```

Reference: [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) 
Stack Overflow Reference: [Math.round(num) vs num.toFixed(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/javascript-functions-math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistenci)

Comment: I's not changing anything, after this i have still 0.0 when i'm trying to type 2200 as a number.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you need to remove the Math.round() as well. This is removing the decimal.