# Reliable JS rounding numbers with toFixed(2) of a 3 decimal number

Tags: javascript, rounding, tofixed

I am simply trying to round up `1.275.toFixed(2)` and I was expecting a return of **1.28**, rather than 1.27.

Using various calculators and the simple method of rounding to the nearest hundredth, if the last digit is greater than **or equal to** five, it *should* round up.

If this doesn't work with toFixed(2), how would it?

People asking whether console.log(1.275.toFixed(2)) prints off 1.28, here's a quick screenshot MacOS Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: please try `console.log(1.275.toFixed(2));` i get `'1.28'`.

Comment: I bet `1.275` is periodic in binary.

Comment: I think this might [vary per browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistencies), I get `1.27` in chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `toFixed()` method is unreliable in its rounding (see [Álvaro González' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110118/3558960) as to why this is the case).

In both current Chrome and Firefox, calling `toFixed()` yields the following inconsistent results:

```
35.655.toFixed(2) // Yields "36.66" (correct)
35.855.toFixed(2) // Yields "35.85" (wrong, should be "35.86")
```

MDN describes a [reliable rounding implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding):

```
// Closure
(function() {
  /**
   * Decimal adjustment of a number.
   *
   * @param {String}  type  The type of adjustment.
   * @param {Number}  value The number.
   * @param {Integer} exp   The exponent (the 10 logarithm of the adjustment base).
   * @returns {Number} The adjusted value.
   */
  function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
    // If the exp is undefined or zero...
    if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0) {
      return Math[type](value);
    }
    value = +value;
    exp = +exp;
    // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
    if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    // Shift
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    value = Math[type](+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp)));
    // Shift back
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp));
  }

  // Decimal round
  if (!Math.round10) {
    Math.round10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('round', value, exp);
    };
  }
  // Decimal floor
  if (!Math.floor10) {
    Math.floor10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('floor', value, exp);
    };
  }
  // Decimal ceil
  if (!Math.ceil10) {
    Math.ceil10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('ceil', value, exp);
    };
  }
})();

// Round
Math.round10(55.55, -1);   // 55.6
Math.round10(55.549, -1);  // 55.5
Math.round10(55, 1);       // 60
Math.round10(54.9, 1);     // 50
Math.round10(-55.55, -1);  // -55.5
Math.round10(-55.551, -1); // -55.6
Math.round10(-55, 1);      // -50
Math.round10(-55.1, 1);    // -60
Math.round10(1.005, -2);   // 1.01 -- compare this with Math.round(1.005*100)/100 above
// Floor
Math.floor10(55.59, -1);   // 55.5
Math.floor10(59, 1);       // 50
Math.floor10(-55.51, -1);  // -55.6
Math.floor10(-51, 1);      // -60
// Ceil
Math.ceil10(55.51, -1);    // 55.6
Math.ceil10(51, 1);        // 60
Math.ceil10(-55.59, -1);   // -55.5
Math.ceil10(-59, 1);       // -50
```

Comment: Perfect, what should I be using as a more reliable method?

Comment: Thank you. I stripped it out to a snippet above.

Answer (score 6):

The `1.275` base 10 number has finite digits but becomes periodic when converted to base 2:

```
= 0b1.01000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
         ^^^^
```

Since it has infinite digits, it cannot be represented exactly in a computer unless you use an arbitrary precision library (a library than represents numbers as text to keep them in base 10). JavaScript numbers do not use such library for performance reasons.

Since the original value has already lost precision when it reaches JavaScript, rounding it will not improve that.

Answer (score 2):

While I am a little late, this could help someone with the same requirement. If the value is a string, simply add an additional "1" to the end and your issue will be fixed.
If `input = 10.55` then it would become `10.551` which in turn would become `10.56`.

This example uses jQuery

```
function toTwoDecimalPlaces(input) {
        var value = $(input).val();
        if (value != null) {
            value = parseFloat(value + "1").toFixed(2);
        }
        $(input).val(value);
}
```

**Update:** If the input is accepting whole numbers and/or numbers with 1 decimal place, then you will want to check how many decimal places have been used. If it is greater than the fixed amount then add the "1".

```
function toTwoDecimalPlaces(input) {
        var value = $(input).val();
        if (value.includes(".")) {
            var splitValue = value.split(".");
            if (splitValue[1].length > 2) {
                value = parseFloat(value + "1").toFixed(2);
            }
        }
        $(input).val(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Custom Function to Round a Number To2 Decimal Places in JavaScript.

```
function roundToTwo(num) {
    return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}

console.log(roundToTwo(2.005));
```

For more information visit https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-round-to-2-decimal-places/

Answer (score 0):

According to Robby's answer, MDN describes a [reliable rounding implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding), therefore I stripped it down to the following snippet to solve my issue of rounding a 3 decimal number of `1.275` to `1.28`. *Tested in FF4, Chrome 55 and Safari 10.0.3 on MacOS*

```
function decimalAdjust(c,a,b){if("undefined"===typeof b||0===+b)return Math[c](a);a=+a;b=+b;if(isNaN(a)||"number"!==typeof b||0!==b%1)return NaN;a=a.toString().split("e");a=Math[c](+(a[0]+"e"+(a[1]?+a[1]-b:-b)));a=a.toString().split("e");return+(a[0]+"e"+(a[1]?+a[1]+b:b))}Math.round10||(Math.round10=function(c,a){return decimalAdjust("round",c,a)});

Math.round10(1.275, -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the simplest solutions, and one I always use. Any number in the `{}` will truncate to that many decimals, my case below to the second decimal `{2}`.

```
let Num = 23.49876
let NumString = Num+''
let toSecondDecimalPlace = NumString.replace(/(.*\.\d{2})(.+)/,'$1'); 
console.log('to Second Decimal Place:', toSecondDecimalPlace) // 23.49

let backToNumber = Number(toSecondDecimalPlace)
console.log('backToNumber:', backToNumber) // 23.49
```

Answer (score 0):

Face it.  If you want a specific rule for what happens when the number is exactly "one-half" in the last place, you should write your own rounding routine.

Alas ECMA decided to ignore IEEE 754 and invent yet another rounding algorithm.  754 defaults to "round to nearest even" -- 3.5 -> 4 and 4.5 -> 4.  This, of course, disagrees with "banking" rules.

The OP has not said what he actually wants for *other* cases.  Their screenshot seems to imply that JavaScript is converting 1.275 to a binary floating point approximation.  (Alvaro provides the details.)

A different JS implementation might store 1.275 in *decimal*, thereby making things work differently.