# Single Digit After Decimal - Javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to round a decimal "94.545". I am getting a different result in C#.Net and Javascript. The following code i am using.

C#:

```
string.Format("{0:0.0}", Convert.ToDouble("94.545")); --> Result 94.6
string.Format("{0:0.0}", Convert.ToDouble("90.769")); --> Result 90.8
```

Javascript:

```
parseFloat('94.545').toFixed(1); --> Result 94.5
parseFloat('90.769').toFixed(1); --> Result 90.8
```

The first value '94.545' is creating issue. I am getting different results between c# and javascript.

I have tried different things, i am getting the same response.

Comment: What do you expect as the correct answer?

Comment: what value you expect is it `floor` or `ceiling ` value? both `javascript` and `c#` has a function for it `Math.Ceiling(value), Math.Floor(value)` use this it would help you i hope

Comment: Just tried it in Linqpad and got 94.5 The conversion is affected by the current thread culture. What is yours set to?

Comment: I am fine with 94.6 or 94.5 (single decimal needed) but both js and c# should return the same.

Comment: It is known that `toFixed()` yields inconsistent rounding for long time. You can try workaround in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliable JS rounding numbers with toFixed(2) of a 3 decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109818/reliable-js-rounding-numbers-with-tofixed2-of-a-3-decimal-number)

Comment: Math.Floor(value) gave some idea...Thanks a lot.