# Rounding a number in Javascript so that it matches C#

Tags: javascript, c#, rounding, rounding-error

I have an application written in nodejs. The application needs to calculate a maritime levy. the calculation needs to match the result from the port. The levy calculator in the port is written in C#.

**NOTE: I Have no control over the C# code. I need to adapt the JS code around what C# is returning**

This is the Javascript code:

```
console.log('Testing rounding -- js')
nrt = 34622
c = 0

if (nrt <= 5000) c = nrt * 0.405
else if (nrt > 5000 && nrt <= 20000) c = 2025 + ( (nrt - 5000) * 0.291)
else if (nrt > 20000 && nrt <= 50000) c = 6390 + ( (nrt - 20000) * 0.24)
else c = 13590 + ( (nrt - 50000) * 0.18)

var p = nrt * 0.1125

var t = c + p

console.log(t)
console.log(t.toFixed(2))
```

Result:

```
Testing rounding -- js
13794.255
13794.25
```

This is the C# code:

```
using System;

namespace sample1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing rounding -- csharp");

            decimal nrt = 34622;
            decimal  c = 0;
            if (nrt <= 5000) c = nrt * (decimal) 0.405;
            else if (nrt > 5000 && nrt <= 20000) c = 2025 + ( (nrt - 5000) * (decimal) 0.291);
            else if (nrt > 20000 && nrt <= 50000) c = 6390 + ( (nrt - 20000) * (decimal) 0.24);
            else c = 13590 + ( (nrt - 50000) * (decimal) 0.18);

            decimal p = nrt * (decimal) 0.1125;

            decimal t = c + p;

            Console.WriteLine(t);
            Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Round(t, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Testing rounding -- csharp
13794.2550
13794.26
```

Please note that I don't know C# at all. I realise that it has a "decimal" type, which is *a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations. It has 28-29 digit Precision*

As far as I know, Javascript doesn't handle a 128-bit data type.

I also wonder whether the problem might well be in different implementation of rounding.

I am writing this as I also add that 13794.2550 is spectacularly hard to round reliably across systems. This is a whole different rabbit hole.

But, for example using a [rounding function blatantly stolen from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101013/829771):

```
function r(n, decimals) {
    return Number((Math.round(n + "e" + decimals)  + "e-" + decimals));
}

console.log(r(13794.2550,2))
console.log(13794.2550.toFixed(2))
```

Result:

```
13794.26 <--- this is what I want! But, is it reliable?
13794.25
```

The rounding function seems to give out the same result. So, maybe I am having a "rounding implementation" problem, rather than a "not enough precision" problem. But, is it reliable?

(That is, is the c# Decimal.Round function implemented exactly as the [rounding function blatantly stolen from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101013/829771)?

Comment: See my edit: I have no control over C#, I need to adapt the JS code so that it does what C# does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are getting is because you are using different type of rounding functions.

In the JS section you are using `toFixed()`  rather than `Math.round()`. toFixed isn't exactly the same as C# rounding. It's more similar to the C# rounding where you add an `AwayFromZero` property to it. You can do this in C# as well but have to be explicit about it about it --> `Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`. You should be able to use `Math.round()` to get the same results as you would in C#. They are both Maintained by Microsoft, so generally they work very similar and sometimes have the same implementations of libraries (from a user perspective).

[Math.round(num) vs num.toFixed(0) and browser inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistencies)

So yes that second implementation that you used is reliable. If you are worried about the 128 byte conversion, trying using `double` instead of `decimal` and check if you have the same results as `double` is 64 bit, and if you need further testing use `float` which is 32 bit.

Comment: +1, but because JavaScript uses floating point math, I would make the tests for reliability in C# with `float` first (and probably not test with `double` at all).

Comment: I am sorry... I forgot to specify more clearly that while I *DO* have total control over the Javascript code, I have zero control over the C# code! Can you please update the answer keeping this in mind?