# Timer in a local scope variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, scope, intervals, let

The timer must be initialized and the seconds have to be incremented each second. Can someone help me? I am not sure what is going on.

```
function timer(){
    let seconds = "00";
    let minutes = "00";
    let hours = "00";
    let fulltime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    const incrementSeconds = () => {
        secondsAsNumber = parseInt(seconds) + 1;
        seconds = secondsAsNumber.toString();
    }
    
    const displayTime = () => {
        console.log(fulltime);
    }
    
    setInterval(() => {
        incrementSeconds();
        displayTime();
    }, 1000);
}

timer();
```

It logs:

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

Comment: You only assign `fulltime` once and never change it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save time value in dynamically created li to input box with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71174215/how-to-save-time-value-in-dynamically-created-li-to-input-box-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `fulltime` variable after incrementing seconds:

```js
function timer(){
    let seconds = "00";
    let minutes = "00";
    let hours = "00";
    let fulltime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    const incrementSeconds = () => {
        secondsAsNumber = parseInt(seconds) + 1;
        seconds = secondsAsNumber.toString();
        // Update fulltime variable
        fulltime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds}`;
    }
    
    const displayTime = () => {
        console.log(fulltime);
    }
    
    setInterval(() => {
        incrementSeconds();
        displayTime();
    }, 1000);
}

timer();
```

Then it should output:

```js
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05

... and so on ...
```

Comment: You rock, man. Thank you! Loved the ternary to insert an "0".

Answer (score 2):

**Here's What u need**

```
function timer() {
    let seconds = "0";
    let minutes = "0";
    let hours = "0";
    let fulltime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    const incrementSeconds = () => {
      let secondsAsNumber = parseInt(seconds) + 1;
      seconds = secondsAsNumber.toString();

      if (seconds > 59) {
        minutes = parseInt(minutes) + 1;
        seconds = 0;
      }
      if (minutes > 59) {
        hours = parseInt(hours) + 1;
        minutes = 0;
      }
      // Update fulltime variable

      fulltime = `${hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours}:${
        minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes
      }:${seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds}`;
    };

    const displayTime = () => {
      console.log(fulltime);
    };

    setInterval(() => {
      incrementSeconds();
      displayTime();
    }, 1000);
  }

  timer();
```