# Shuffle a container's DOM elements but not all in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, shuffle

Trying to shuffle a container's (a div) DOM elements (other divs) with a particular class name ("div"). Other divs ("extra") should stay put in the place where they are.

So far I have used the modified shuffle algorithm from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070054/javascript-shuffle-html-list-element-order)

The code I have almost did the trick but the "Extra" div is appended at the bottom of the stack while it's supposed to stay atop.

```js
let divs       = document.getElementsByClassName("div")
let divsNumber = divs.length;
let divver     = document.getElementsByClassName("divver")[0]

function shuffler() {
  for (var i = divsNumber; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!divver.children[i].classList.contains("div")) {
      divver.appendChild(divver.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divver">
  <div class="extra">  Extra  </div>
  <div class="div">    1  </div>
  <div class="div">    2  </div>
  <div class="div">    3  </div>
  <div class="div">    4  </div>
  <div class="div">    5  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="shuffler()" id="shuffles">Shuffle 'em</button>
```

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrap extras and shuffled divs to separate wrappers, shuffle only needed elements

Comment: Use [`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to get the wanted divs from `#divver`. No need for checking anything, just append randomly.

Comment: Will the html *always* have only one static `extra` div at index `0`? Or could there be multiple `extra` divs at various indices? If the latter, I would modify the question to have at least one additional `extra` at another position in the child elements

Comment: Teemu, yours as well as Mr Jojo's below, are the ones with the least amount of code modifications needed which also steered me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: For a better readability it is preferable to use `Math.floor(x)` instead of `x | 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const
  divver      = document.querySelector('div.divver')
, ShuffleDivs = [...divver.querySelectorAll('div:not(.extra)')]
  ;
document.querySelector('button#shuffles').onclick = () =>
  {
  let r_Idx; // random Index;

  // current index from  ShuffleDivs.length -1 to zero
  for ( let c_Idx = ShuffleDivs.length; c_Idx--; )  
    {
    // Pick one.. in the range[ 0 ... c_Idx]
    r_Idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * c_Idx);      

    // swap Array positions
    [ShuffleDivs[c_Idx], ShuffleDivs[r_Idx]] =
    [ShuffleDivs[r_Idx], ShuffleDivs[c_Idx]]; 
    }

  // replace them in the new Shuffle order...
  for (let i = 0; i < ShuffleDivs.length; i++)
    divver.appendChild(ShuffleDivs[i]);
  }
```

```html
<div class="divver">
  <div class="extra"> Extra </div>
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
</div>

<button id="shuffles">Shuffle 'em</button>
```

> To avoid moving pointers to DOM elements,
> I just use the indexing of their position on the interface here (aOrder):

```js
const
  divver      = document.querySelector('div.divver')
, ShuffleDivs = divver.querySelectorAll('div:not(.extra)')
, aOrder      = Array.from(ShuffleDivs,(_,i)=>i)  // array of elements position order
  ;
document.querySelector('button#shuffles').onclick = () =>
  {
  let r; // random Index;

  for ( let c = aOrder.length; c--; ) //  current Index; 
    {
    r = 0|(Math.random() * c);        // Pick one range[ 0 ... c]
    [aOrder[c], aOrder[r]] = [aOrder[r], aOrder[c]]; // swap positions
    }
  for (let pos of aOrder)   
    divver.appendChild(ShuffleDivs[pos]);
  }
```

```html
<div class="divver">
  <div class="extra">  Extra  </div>
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
</div>

<button id="shuffles">Shuffle 'em</button>
```

for the record...

comment from **ViliusL**

> "1" is always on bottom.

Exact!
the previous algorithm always leaves the first element at the end.
Indeed, the initial collection is always read in the same order.

I fixed it by changing the collection of divs to Array so I could actually change their order.
So any new shuffle will be based on their actual position.

*First "incorrect" answer:*

```
const
  divver      = document.querySelector('div.divver')
, ShuffleDivs = divver.querySelectorAll('div.div') // just select this group
  ;
document.querySelector('button#shuffles').onclick = () =>
  {
  for (let i = ShuffleDivs.length; i >= 0; i--)
    divver.appendChild(ShuffleDivs[Math.random() * i | 0]);
  }
```

Comment: Mister Jojo, yours as well as Teemu's above, are the ones with the least amount of code modifications needed which also steered me on the right track. Thanks.
Unfortunately, I have too few points on stackoverflow myself to grant them to contributors.

Comment: "1" is always on bottom.

Comment: @ViliusL You're right, I have updated my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

Since you wish to leave the first element out of the shuffle and arrays of elements are 0 based you can change `* i | 0]` to `* i | 1]`

```js
let divs       = document.getElementsByClassName("div")
let divsNumber = divs.length;
let divver     = document.getElementsByClassName("divver")[0]

function shuffler() {
  for (var i = divsNumber; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!divver.children[i].classList.contains("div")) {
      divver.appendChild(divver.children[Math.random() * i | 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divver">
  <div class="extra">  Extra  </div>
  <div class="div">    1  </div>
  <div class="div">    2  </div>
  <div class="div">    3  </div>
  <div class="div">    4  </div>
  <div class="div">    5  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="shuffler()" id="shuffles">Shuffle 'em</button>
```

Comment: Should have thought of that myself. Brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: I down vote because your example doesn't work: it does a rotate in place of shuffle. `Math.random() * i | 1` will always return a odd number

Comment: @Yukulélé Fair enough on that point - I focused on the question "leave that one div alone and out of scope" vs the validity of the OP's shuffle algorithm.  I will leave this in place just for that reason. FWIW I would have likely done this differently; especially the markup than the OP but simply answered the basic question.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Unfortunately the code you provide does not give the expected behavior.

Comment: `floatNumber | 0` proceed to return the integer part of the float.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077449/fastest-way-to-cast-a-float-to-an-int-in-javascript