# Javascript syntax of "a= object,object"

Tags: javascript, syntax

Yesterday I found this function:

```
function clone(obj) {
    return typeof obj === 'undefined' ?
        this : (clone.prototype = Object(obj), new clone);
}
```

I though that i saw alot in Javascript, but this syntax is unknown for me:

```
 clone.prototype = Object(obj), new clone
```

Can someone explain me how to read this?? Can you give me link to proper definition ? I couldn't find it in Mozilla's MDC, and dont know how to find this on web, but this is first time ever I saw that syntax. Thanks for effort here.

Final solution:

I did some testing according to answers here and there is what I found:

```
var b;
b=alert('test'),6;
alert(b);  // alert undefined
b=5,alert('test2');
alert(b);  // alert 5
```

Thanks to christoph research we found more:

```
var a, b, c;
a = 1, 2;   // a is 1
(b = 1), 2; // b is 1 - same as above!
c = (1, 2); // c is 2
```

Ahh and I tested it also on IE6 and it works, so this have to be realy old syntax and there is no information about it? :( Strange...

Both of you guys gave good solution, thanks for solution here!

Comment: Section 11.14 in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf     Try: alert((1,2,3,4));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'final solution' gives unexpected results because of operator precedence. The following example might help to clarify the issue:

```
var a, b, c;
a = 1, 2;   // a is 1
(b = 1), 2; // b is 1 - same as above!
c = (1, 2); // c is 2
```

Also notice that

```
var a = 1, 2;
```

produces a syntax error!

Comment: Yes I noticed that "var a" and simple a does not. Thats very interesting syntax here. Nice catch with bracers there.

Answer (score 7):

[Comma operator at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator):

> The comma operator (,) simply
>   evaluates both of its operands and
>   returns the value of the second
>   operand.

In this case it does work like calling this function:

```
function() {
   clone.prototype = Object(obj);
   return new clone;
}
```

Comment: @sth: This is almost what I wanted to hear, but mine research gives me a little diffrent result (see Final solution revision)