# CSS display: inline-block doesn't work in IE7

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-7

I created this to simply explain my problem. It is of some list items being displayed as inline blocks. I had an original method that didn't work either, so I used this [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628407/hidden-features-of-css/1973313#1973313).

http://jsbin.com/upexu/edit

This works great in FF and IE7, as a standalone.

Unfortunately, in my implementation on my site, it doesn't display correctly in IE7 (they appear stacked one above the other).

### Firefox

[image: firefox]

### IE7

[image: ie7]

Now can anyone tell me why they don't work in my example (see images above and look at site, it is in the far right (can't miss it).

It seems to work in IE7 if I give the list items an explicit width - but this seems dangerous, as well as an extra piece of maintenance I don't want to do. I could probably do `li#nsw { width: 3.5em }` but is ugly and I *shouldn't* have to.

I do use [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/).

If you know of a solution, please tell!

Thanks.

### Update

Here is the HTML of the checkboxes

```
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li><input type="radio" id="free-case-review-nsw" value="nsw" name="state" /><label for="free-case-review-nsw"><acronym title="New South Wales">NSW</acronym></label></li>

    <li><input type="radio" checked="checked" id="free-case-review-qld" value="qld" name="state" /><label for="free-case-review-qld"><acronym title="Queensland">QLD</acronym></label></li>

    <li><input type="radio" id="free-case-review-nt" value="nt" name="state" /><label for="free-case-review-nt"><acronym title="Northern Territory">NT</acronym></label></li>

    <li><input type="radio" id="free-case-review-other" value="other" name="state" /><label for="free-case-review-other">Other</label></li>
  </ul>
```

And here is the CSS

```
 #free-case-review-form .checkboxes {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #free-case-review-form .checkboxes li {
        display: inline-block;
        display: -moz-inline-box;
        *display: inline; /* for ie */
        zoom: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #free-case-review-form .checkboxes li input {
        display: inline;
        width: auto;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }

    #free-case-review-form .checkboxes li label {
        display: inline; /* just an attempt - they should be block level anyway */
        float: right;
    }
```

Though I do recommend looking at the site above, as a lot more CSS is inherited, especially by using the style reset.

Comment: You should post the actual html + css.  It's hard to get the html from the site because the html is built

Comment: That header is really evil! Specially because as it isn't done in flash Flashblock didn't block it :P I wan't my webpages as my car trips: unsurprising and with little unexpected movements/distractions.

Comment: You can use FireBug to view the HTML from the form. I'll post an excerpt anyway,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Far as I can tell, it's the "float: right" on the css for the label.  Whatever you are doing, try doing it without setting the float: right on the label.

when I removed "float: right" it went back to inline on my IE.

Comment: +1 and accepted answer - because you answered with my solution as I was typing it :D

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you accidentally triggered [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) on 1 of the children, either the `input` or the `label`

Comment: Perhaps, except I float the input left and the label right, meaning they will automatically become block level elements right? Thanks for your answer.