# CSS styling of flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, stylesheet

What should I use to style my flash messages in my CSS? I can't seem to change it's styling. Here's the relevant code within the `<body>` of my application layout:

```
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <section class="round">
        <div id= "notice">
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
            <div class="flash <%= key %>">
              <%= value %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
```

The relevant original CSS was something like this but it doesn't currently work.

```
.error, .alert, .notice, .success, .info {padding:0.8em;margin-bottom:1em;border:2px solid #ddd;}
.success {background:#e6efc2;color:#264409;border-color:#c6d880;}
```

Comment: What's the CSS like? ANd what is the generated HTML output?

Comment: For the HTML and CSS you are using, this should work. Are you sure you're including the CSS file in your header? If it's the Rails tutorial, you should have `render 'layouts/stylesheets'` a bit farther in your layout, which should in turn have `stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen'` in it (in `app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb`). See [here](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml#L8) and [here](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.haml) (although I'm using Haml).

Comment: Yep it is blueprint's CSS and I definitely am including the CSS file. Not sure why styling doesn't work all of a sudden but it must have something to do with the ajax rendering I just implemented for it.

Comment: Inspect the HTML and ensure that the classnames you expect are being set.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the `<div id="notice"></div>` I added around the block so that the ajax would have an id to `getElementbyId`?

Comment: Use FireBug (or IE 8's developer tools) to check what the browser thinks which CSS it was supposed to apply (and why).

Comment: Maybe the key is printing out as a symbol, try "key.to_s" instead of "key"

Comment: This is probably insignificant, but try getting rid of the space between id= and "notice"

Comment: Alright here's what's happening. The CSS is not responding to the `flash` or `<%= key %>` classes, but it is responding to the `notice` id. Unfortunately, if I style with the `notice` id, some styling appears that should be dependent on whether there is a flash message or not. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you posting this question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197677/weird-css-conundrum

Comment: Because literally no one has been able to figure this out, so once I make a little leeway on the issue, I want to post the question again with my new information. No one on SO has been significantly helpful with this issue, and everyone seems to misunderstand it.

Answer (score 3):

Either add a rule for parent div with id notice:

```
#notice {
  css_formatting_here
}
```

Or add a rule for child divs:

```
.flash {
  css_formatting_here
}
```

The child div of errors container has multiple classes separated by whitespace. `flash` is one of them. Thus you can add a CSS rule for that class, and it will work.

Look here for more such examples: [Hidden features of CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628407/hidden-features-of-css/954669#954669)

Comment: Alright here's what's happening. The CSS is not responding to the flash or <%= key %> classes, but it is responding to the notice id. Unfortunately, if I style with the notice id, some styling appears that should be dependent on whether there is a flash message or not. How can I fix this

Comment: @Justin Meltzer - can you give a raw HTML output of the div in question, not Rails code?

Comment: It's not helpful. It just shows a div with the text inside and id `notice` Here's all of my code: https://github.com/meltzerj/sample_app

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the CSS calls for a class `.notice`, but the div has an ID instead.

EDIT

> The CSS is not responding to the flash
>   or <%= key %> classes, but it is
>   responding to the notice id.
>   Unfortunately, if I style with the
>   notice id, some styling appears that
>   should be dependent on whether there
>   is a flash message or not. How can I
>   fix this

You could add a conditional test around the div:

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
  <div id="notice">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="flash <%= key %>">
        <%= value %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The code in question is: `<div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>`, not the line above it.

Comment: Alright, alright! What, I have to actually *read* the questions now? Sheesh.

Comment: Could you please remove this answer to give more visibility to the question? Thx

Comment: @Brandon Tilley - root element of that div has ID notice

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by root element, but this is the problem:  The CSS is not responding to the flash or <%= key %> classes, but it is responding to the notice id. Unfortunately, if I style with the notice id, some styling appears that should be dependent on whether there is a flash message or not. How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

In your css file type:

```
.alert-success {
    dosomestyling;
}

.alert-danger {
    dosomestyling;
}
```