# Weird CSS conundrum

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ajax

So for some reason the following html code only responds to the `notice` id and not the `flash` or `<%=key%>` classes in my CSS. Why is that? Also, I have some styling which should exist depending on whether I'm showing the flash message or not. However, using the `notice` id for styling, the CSS always shows up. However, I need the `notice` id for my ajax rendering of the flash message. How can I solve this problem?

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <section class="round">
    <div id= "notice">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="flash <%= key %>">
          <%= value %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
  </section>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.error, .alert, .notice, .success, #notice, .info {
     padding:0.8em;
     margin-bottom:1em;
     border:2px solid #ddd;
}
#notice {
     background:#e6efc2;
     color:#264409;
     border-color:#c6d880;
}
```

And here's the relevant html output. Note that it's only the div.

```
<section class="round">
  <div id= "notice"></div> 
  <!-- yielded content -->
</section>
```

Comment: Could you add the pure HTML output, and the relevant CSS? (not my downvote)

Comment: theres no flash class in what you have posted...

Comment: yea there is: <div class="flash <%= key %>">

Comment: That's two classes: one is `flash`, the other is the output of `<%=key%>`

Comment: in the css i mean you dont have flash in there.  so how do you expect it to respond to a flash class in your css if it doesnt exist?

Comment: Could you add the pure HTML after Ruby has been executed? :)

Comment: Just the empty `div` is not going to help us. If you use firefox, you can select your flash message, right-click and view the source of the html including the stuff returned by ajax.

Comment: This is literally what is returned by ajax:`<div id="notice"> Micropost created!</div>`

Comment: @Justin Meltzer It seems there is no problem to solve, the classes you mention are not applied anywhere in the html so the styles are never used.

Comment: Im very confused. Why is this happening??? I define the classes in my html and in my CSS, and I link in my stylesheets. Why does this weird stuff always happen to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS styling of flash message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190090/css-styling-of-flash-message)

Answer (score 0):

well in your CSS the class is defined wrong:

```
.notice{}
```

it should be declared with an id selector (#) since you use an id (versus the class selector .)

```
#notice{}
```

Also, there is no flash class defined
So in your CSS, just add something like this:

```
.flash{color:#F00}
```

more or less see in action here (just pasted ur html and add the flash class): http://jsfiddle.net/gmedina/uMCDM/1/

Comment: well, the updated CSS still missing something like this `.flash{}`

Comment: well what should my CSS look like? that's what im asking

Comment: check it out, added a flash class to the css http://jsfiddle.net/gmedina/uMCDM/1/

Comment: It's not quite so simple because some styling appears that shouldn't when there is no message. Would you mind taking a look at my code at https://github.com/meltzerj/sample_app

Answer (score 0):

It´s hard to say without seeing the complete html and css, but if you are setting a style for your notice id like `#notice {}`, you can´t override it with the css you posted: `.error, .alert, .notice, .success, .info {}` as an ID has a higher value in the cascade than a class (100 vs 10 if I´m not mistaken).

To override settings from `#notice` you will need:

```
#notice .alert {
}
// etc.
```

Comment: yeah, i had posted the wrong CSS. I reposted the right CSS. the question may make more sense now

Answer (score -1):

you need to parse the key value as a string.  try

```
<div class="flash <%= '#{key}' %>">
```

Comment: well you could always try something like this: '<%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>'

Comment: its a helper that will render the div that you have now.  since your problem seems to be the div not rendering correctly this should do the trick if the problem is with your embedded ruby.  worth a shot in any case

Comment: what should this replace? should i get rid of the <div id="notice">?

Comment: no get rid of everything between <% flash.each %> and <% end %> and just put that there

Comment: `value` is undefined, do you mean #{value}

Comment: are you passing a flash message from your action?

Comment: yeah, i set it in the controller

Comment: might as well post your controller code then too. value being undefined hints at there being a problem sending that from the controller to the view

Comment: you can check out my code at https://github.com/meltzerj/sample_app   feel free to fork it