# :before and :after pseudo elements on html tag is wonky in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

I'm trying to learn how to use the :before and :after pseudo elements. I'm trying to add a black background to the bottom of the page as a sticky footer but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Basically I have a repeating image as the background of the HTML element and then I add an absolute div positioned at the bottom with a solid black background.

I'd just like to point out that this is a learning experiment and not really how I'd achieve the same effect but what I'm trying is working in Firefox but not in Chrome!

Here's my CSS:

```css
html {
    background-image: url('images/template/html-bg.jpg');
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

html:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 138px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

In FF the page is rendered as I'd expect but in Chrome the whole page is black... Any ideas, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: there is nothing "before" the html tag, aside from the DOCTYPE, 
i don't think that is valid CSS.

Comment: So I should only use these pseudo elements on elements within the body tags?

Comment: yes use in body instead of HTML tag

Comment: Anyone want to put it as an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: @Andres Ilich: 1) That's not how these pseudo-elements work. 2) What does the DOCTYPE have to do with CSS? This is perfectly valid CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock According to spec the :before and :after pseudo elements are used to place content before or after an element. In this case some blank content is being placed before the html tag, where the only thing that is there is the DOCTYPE so just noting that.

Comment: @Andres Ilich: I misread your initial comment. However, you've also misread the spec. It places content before/after an element's content, not before/after the element itself.

Comment: @BoltClock you know, i had doubts about that before, you just cleared it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CSS should work as expected, as your pseudo-element should be drawn in the context of the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) (the viewport, represented by the `html` element) anyway, which is exactly what Firefox is doing.

Your particular issue was reported as a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75544), but it hasn't been addressed. As a workaround, you can apply your pseudo-element to `body` instead:

```css
body:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 138px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Depending on your layout, you may need to either keep your `html` rule or change it to `body` as well.

Comment: That's exactly what it is! I feel special having come across a Chrome bug :P Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't believe it's a bug per se. Is `HTML` supposed to have "content" at all? HTML is the canvas. I wouldn't be surprised if a browser would implicitly slap `display:none` on all elements within a HTML element except `<body>`. Otherwise you'd always have some whitespace in the DOM tree above and below the body.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Here's my take: `html` is the root element in the DOM. `head` and `body` are its children, both of which are also represented as DOM nodes. The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements describe inserting content before or after an element's document tree content, so they *should* work with the `html` element because its document tree content consists of the `head` and `body` elements. Like you said, `html` is the "canvas", where visual elements are drawn, and `head` does have an initial style of `display: none` anyway.

Comment: I can go with most of that, but not your punchline "head does have an initial style of display: none anyway." That cannot possibly be true, because the children of an element with `display:none` are never drawn, never! [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop), "This behavior **cannot** be overridden by setting the 'display' property on the descendants." SeaMonkey's DOM Inspector also tells me that the HTML element of this page has `display:block`.

Comment: @Mr Lister: [So just set `display: block` on the `head` element too!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138137/106224)