# Why the :before and :after pseudo-elements work only in Firefox?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've created a `select` list with options having `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8cvQ/3/)

```css
option:after, option::before {
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background: #c00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However this works in Firefox only and no other browser.

As it stated on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#before-after-content), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aafter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Aafter), [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after) the `:after` is a "*pseudo-element rendered after the matched element and used to add cosmetic content*" and nobody states **any** restriction about elements it can't be applied to.

Question - why all the browsers (except FF) can't properly display the pseudo-elements? 
Any documentation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SitePoint's description is inaccurate. MDN's description comes closer to what's in the spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether there is a restriction is undefined, hence the inconsistent behavior. This is mentioned at the bottom of the relevant section in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> **Note.** This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

Most HTML form elements are considered replaced elements, including `select` and `option`.

Comment: Thanks. That *kind of* makes sense - [replaced elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements), at the same time the `:first-letter` [fails](http://jsfiddle.net/V8cvQ/9/) in *all* browsers

Comment: @ZoltanToth: But the `:first-letter` pseudo element can only be applied to block-level elements.

Comment: @w3d - that's true, but it fails regardless of that http://jsfiddle.net/V8cvQ/12/

Comment: @w3d: Specifically it can only apply to a block container (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-letter). In this case, `option` isn't a block container.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this: [:before and :after pseudo elements on html tag is wonky in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790000/before-and-after-pseudo-elements-on-html-tag-is-wonky-in-chrome) ?

The accepted answer said that is an issue in Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75544