# Select box elements and :after

Tags: css, select, pseudo-element

Why doesnt it work? Is there a work around for this without adding an extra element?

http://jsfiddle.net/86gb2/

Comment: look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11903273/1499781

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3532649/630321

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your fiddle the following declaration is probably not doing what you expect.

```
select:after {content: "This doesn't work";}
```

This will actually append the text ***after the content*** of the select box, not after the select box itself. So that text is being added after the last `option` in the markup. (Which of course is neither valid, nor will it be rendered by the browser.)

In other words if you had this markup:

```
<a href="#">My link</a>
```

and this CSS:

```
a:after {content: " has now been appended to";}
```

What is actually happening is this:

```
<a href="#">My link has now been appended to</a>
```

Comment: I know that. But i didnt think of it when it was for the select element..I used a wrapper instead, then it worked like i wanted :)

Comment: Just a reminder that `:after` and `:before` _don’t_ mean after or before the element, but after and before the _content_ inside. In the case of a `select` element, any content that’s not an `option` element is invalid, so it’s ignored.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend to use jQuery API for such things:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").after("<div>this doesnt work, or does it?</div>");
});​
```