# Why isn't img:after working?

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this question already exists, but I didn't manage to find it. I am wondering why img:after in CSS is not working. I tried setting the display of the img to be block and what not, but it refuses to work every time...Any ideas? I am trying to place a background image after an image (for oldschool shadow), but it works only if I place the image in a div/span.

That's what I've been trying to run:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercise2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exercise2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJxP3c9QZ--VxiX0M1p9shvBa0KDLGjTjlqC3V4ygH_zA6vn-Bvw">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.shadow:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    top: 10%;
    content: "";
    height: 90%;
    width: 6px;
    background: url(pictures/shadow_side.png) repeat-y 0% 0%;
}
```

Comment: This is answered here (by spec).... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903273/why-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-only-in-firefox

Comment: Most browsers don't support it. According to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags

Comment: You don't even use `.shadow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the [`:after` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) as something like `:last-child`. It adds a pseudo-element *within* the containing element, after the element's document tree. [Images](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) have an *empty* [content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model), meaning you cannot place another element (or pseudo-element) inside them.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The determining factor is not whether an element has a empty content model, but whether it is a replaced element or not. As proof, see http://jsfiddle.net/ZeAj4/ where the void element `meta` is used yet its `:before` pseudo-element content is rendered nonetheless.

Comment: @Alohci That makes sense; do you know of a place in the specification that states that more explicitly? [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content) only connects them to the *content* of an element.

Comment: I don't unfortunately. I have to say I've always found the specs rather sparse on the matter of replaced elements. It seems like they fall down the gap between HTML and CSS, so I've taken to just testing for de-facto behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The specs says

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with > replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future > specification.

So that would probably mean, that :after and :before don't work with img elements

Answer (score 1):

Images contain nothing inside them (they close themselves). And since the `:before` and `:after` append stuff inside the element (check out [this awesome article by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after/)), you cannot simply just add some stuff by the `:before` and `:after` selectors in an `<img>` tag.

And even if you could, your `<img>` tag has no `class="shadow"`, which it should have.