# How to get CSS pseudo-elements to look the same cross browser?

Tags: css, css-selectors, attr, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Here is a very basic demo of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Open in **Google Chrome**: http://jsfiddle.net/8EbxG/4/

It should look like there's **nothing there, except for a grey rectangle**.

Now, open in IE9, or Firefox.

You will see an empty white rectangle contained within the larger grey one.

What do I need to do to get this looking like it does in chrome **Chrome** cross browser (I haven't even tested older IE, or Opera, or Safari)?

Comment: Take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790000/before-and-after-pseudo-elements-on-html-tag-is-wonky-in-chrome

Comment: @afshin: I think that's different.

Comment: This is very definitely a Chrome bug, though. The ideal scenario is to get Chrome working like Firefox and IE9... not the other way around. If you don't want the white box to be there, then remove the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css:

```
#sb-caption:empty {display:none;}
```

Comment: I think you got it! That was what Firefox was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Delete content:""; and it will work on all browsers

Comment: You can also delete the `::before` and `::after` rules altogether.

Comment: I need the padding to be there in the event that there is text in the white box.

Comment: Actually if you delete `content:""` then pseudo-elements break completely, on most browsers.

Comment: @vitaly87: That's because when you delete it the pseudo-elements disappear altogether. It's by design, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

use Hex color code instead of rgba code

```
 #sb-caption{height:auto; font:12px/36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; position:absolute; right:10px; bottom:10px; background:#ccc}
```

and use space " " or some text in html

```
<div id="sb-wrapper">
  <div id="sb-caption">&nbsp;</div>
</div>​
```

:D

Comment: Why a hex color and not an RGBA color?

Comment: I'll test out the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I recently remembered that IE requires a DOCTYPE to be specified for pseudo-elements to work.

> So, when a DOCTYPE is enetered, the box disappears (in **IE9**, at least).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And, thanks to **manishie** for suggesting to use:

> #sb-caption:empty {display:none;}

I'm pretty sure, that it's what was needed to for **Firefox** to work.

> *Note:* I'm using this method to create a caption `<div>` in **shadowbox.js**.
> Text is fed into `<div id="#sb-caption"></div>` via JavaScript, using `<a rev=""></a>`
>
> **EXAMPLE:**  `<a href="LINK" rev="YOUR CAPTION">`
>
> `rev=""` is where your caption text would go. Which would then go into the `<div>`
>
> This is a small part of a convoluted work-around/hack for shadowbox.

**Here is the FINAL VERSION:**

For **Chrome** and **Firefox** see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FBwQd/
(it wont work in IE because JS-fiddle doesn't recognize DOCTYPE)

For **IE** (and/or **Chrome**) you can see it here: http://cssdesk.com/Mrwh8

You can **remove** the words **'TEST'** to see the Box Disappear completely!

Answer (score 0):

I did some more reading about pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes.
I found that you can also replace (method 1):

> `.sb-caption:empty{display:none;}`
>   `.sb-caption:before{content:"";padding-left:50px;}`
>   `.sb-caption:after{content:"";padding-right:20px;}​`

with (method 2):

> `.caption:empty{display:none;}`
>   `div[class="caption"]{padding-left:50px;padding-right:20px;}`

This, second, method is apparently accepted by older versions of IE, but with some undesirable results anyway.

In both cases, the HTML stays the same:

> `<div>`
>   `<div class="sb-wrapper">`
>   `<div class="sb-caption">TEST</div>`
>   `</div>​`

If you remove the words `'TEST'`, the `#sbcaption` div will disappear in both cases.
Tested in the **latest** versions of **Chrome**, **Firefox**, **IE**, and **Safari**.

If anyone else has another hack, or other way of achieving the same effect (but being even more cross browser friendly ... IE7) please share!

**You can see both effects on this test page: http://djpolbeeta.com/test-index.html**
*(temporary link)*

Open in any browser. The darker rectangle is CSS method 1, the lighter rectange is CSS method 2.

Comment: I've done more testing. Now 100% Positive that  `.caption:empty{display:none;}  
div[class="caption"]{padding-left:50px;padding-right:20px;}`  is the best solution for new browsers.

Comment: Also you can add `#sb-caption[type=""]{visibility:hidden;}` although this will not help IE6