# Can anyone explain the difference between closure and anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript. I understand the concept of anonymous functions - but closures seem less clear. The similarity between the two (in my mind atleast), is confusing.

Could someone explain the difference? (preferrably, with some code snippet, to illustrate the points clearer).

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622421/what-are-the-use-cases-for-closures-callback-functions-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this article? http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html

This could also be good as a starting point: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml

Answer (score 8):

The important difference is that a closure captures the scope it was defined in.

In other words, a closure may access variables and their state even though they belong to the closure's parent scope (e.g. the function the closure was created in). This allows closures to capture and "transport" application state around your program.

An anonymous function cannot do that; its reach is limited to variables defined inside its body and signature (i.e., its parameters).

EDIT: Just to clarify: In JavaScript it is especially unclear since there is no language construct called closure. You'd still use an anonymous function for that. I was only referring to the conceptual difference.

Answer (score 2):

I explained this here: [The Zen of Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2047391#2047391).

Basically, without going into technical details:

- an anonymous function is a function without a name (that can be assigned to variables).
- a closure is a kind of private global variable

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous function is one which does not have any name to it, rest is same as the normal functions in Javascript.
Here is an ex.
Case 1:
This is just some normal/regular javascript function

```
var sayHello = function iWillSayHello(name){
     var fullName = "Hello, " + name; 
     console.log(fullName);
}
sayHello("ABC");    // prints--->  Hello, ABC
```

Case 2:
This is Annonymous function, 
It is the same function with the same behavior as above,

```
var sayHello = function(name){
     var fullName = "Hello, " + name; 
     console.log(fullName);
}
sayHello("ABC");    // prints--->  Hello, ABC
```

Case 3:
If(I think) by "anonymous function" you mean IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Execution),
that is this,

```
(function(name){
     var fullName = "Hello, " + name; 
     console.log(fullName);
})();     // prints--->  Hello, ABC
```

The difference here is, In "Case 1" and "Case 2" you have to call the function explicitly, BUT in "Case 3" it is invoked automatically (i.e. with "()" at the end you are calling it as it is declared).
It will be called as compiler reaches that line.

Clouser, on the other hand, *is a function inside a function*.
What makes a Clouser a special in js, is it still can access the values of the variable from the **"local scope"** of the outer function even if the outer function has returned.

**Clouser = function + outer context**

here is a simple example,

```
function outerSayHello(firstName){
    var fullName = firstName;
    function innerSayHello(lastName){
         console.log("Hello, ", fullName + " " + lastName);
    }

    return innerSayHello;
}

console.log("1-------------------------");
var sayHello = outerSayHello("A");
sayHello("B");
//Hello,  A B

console.log("2-------------------------");
var sayHello1 = outerSayHello("A1");
sayHello1("B1");
//Hello,  A1 B1

console.log("3-------------------------");
sayHello("b");
//Hello,  A b

console.log("4-------------------------");
sayHello1("b1");
//Hello,  A1 b1

console.log("5-------------------------");
outerSayHello("ABC")("XYZ");
//Hello,  ABC XYZ

to better understand these let's console the sayHello variable

console.log("6-------------------------",sayHello);
/*
  innerSayHello(lastName){
         console.log("Hello, ", fullName + " " + lastName);
    }
*/
```

What it means is *sayHello* variable has pointer/reference to the *innerSayHello* function.
And because *innerSayHello* is relying on *fullName* variable, it will still be maintained on the heap, and fullName and *innerSayHello* still be on the stack even after *outerSayHello* returns.
So in the heap, it will create multiple references for fullname and innerSayHello.